# How can I roll my own PyPI? For example, for 'egg' distribution

Tags: python, pypi

I would like to run my own internal PyPI server, for [egg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192) distribution within my organization.

I have found a few projects, such as:

- *[EggBasket](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/EggBasket/)*
- http://plone.org/products/plonesoftwarecenter

As I understand it, pypi.python.org uses software called Cheese Shop.

My questions:

1. Why can't I use Cheese Shop itself?  (I can't find it and am not sure it exists)
2. How do other people solve this problem?  (Currently we use *blush* [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) to distribute 'eggs')

This seems canonical: *[The Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/)*, *[Python Implementations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations)*.  Still, I'm interested in feedback.

How can I roll my own PyPI?

Comment: The main reason for the clones is that the pypi code is horrible :)

Comment: We tried to assemble all dependencies in a buildout script @ [Buildout crate.io](https://github.com/InQuant/buildout_crate.io)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052217/611007

Comment: The second link is broken (plone.org): *"This page does not seem to exist…"*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update: PyPi is now powered by [Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse), which is the replacement for Cheese Shop.**

The source to Cheese Shop can be downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/src. There is also an example, from the page you linked to, of using Apache as a "dumb" Python package repository:

```
# Mount pypi repositories into URI space
Alias /pypi   /var/pypi

# /pypi/dev: Redirect for unknown packages (fallback to pypi)
RewriteCond   /var/pypi/dev/$1 !-d
RewriteCond   /var/pypi/dev/$1 !-f
RewriteRule   ^/pypi/dev/([^/]+)/?$ http://pypi.python.org/pypi/$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond   /var/pypi/dev/$1/$2 !-f
RewriteRule   ^/pypi/dev/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://pypi.python.org/pypi/$1/$2 [R,L]

# /pypi/stable: Redirect for unknown packages (fallback to pypi)
RewriteCond   /var/pypi/stable/$1 !-d
RewriteCond   /var/pypi/stable/$1 !-f
RewriteRule   ^/pypi/stable/([^/]+)/?$ http://pypi.python.org/pypi/$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond   /var/pypi/stable/$1/$2 !-f
RewriteRule   ^/pypi/stable/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://pypi.python.org/pypi/$1/$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: After investigating all of the available options, I am not satisfied with any of them.  However, the apache solution is the simplest, and is what I ended up using, even if it is far from ideal.

Answer (score 22):

For a lightweight solution, use [pypiserver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver).

Answer (score 9):

## [Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse)

[Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse) would be your best bet in 2017. From the project's README:

> Warehouse is a next generation Python Package Repository designed to replace
>   the legacy code base that currently powers [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/)

...

> You can run Warehouse locally using `docker` and `docker-compose`. See
>   [Getting started](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/development/getting-started/)
>   in the documentation for instructions on how to set it up.

It is maintained by [The Python Packaging Authority (PyPA)](https://www.pypa.io/) who work in cooperation with members of the Python core development team, and there is a **live version running at https://pypi.org/** which mirrors everything in the legacy PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/).

Comment: I started a small EC2 instance to use as pypi server with 15GB of hard drive. All the containers needed by warehouse didn't fit in that drive!

Answer (score 6):

## [**devpi**](https://www.devpi.net/)

We are using it in a corporate environment and are pretty satisfied. It supports replication, private indexes and index inheritance.

Comment: How do you guys add more packages to devpi ?

Comment: The interface is the same as pypi. You can use twine to upload packages. There are some access settings that need to be enabled in the devpi server though.

Answer (score 5):

There is a fork of djangopypi named djangopypi2 you can get it from https://github.com/popen2/djangopypi2/, I installed it and works for me, this option is what I had choose from a list of about 24 alternatives that I have found in a recently search, you can see the list here: http://uyeya.blogspot.com/2013/10/list-of-local-alternatives-of-pypi.html

Answer (score 2):

Updated: crate.io has shut down and the domain is now something else entirely.

One project that hasn't been mentioned is https://crate.io/, which seems very active. It claims to be a "Next Generation Python Packaging Index", but they have their repositories split nicely into pieces that seem to welcome customization and remixing to your purposes.

Comment: It looks as though the crate.io domain has now been repurposed?

Comment: And now that lin is dead :p

Comment: @Mark Think I found the GitHub, at least: https://github.com/crateio/crate.io. Superseded by [Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse), according to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1wcp93/what_happened_to_crateio/).

Comment: This project is no longer under active development.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a lighter solution than deploying an entire PyPI server, you could try using a server index generated by [basketweaver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/basketweaver).

Comment: Important to note that BasketWeaver **doesn't have a clue about wheels** and that its latest release was in 2009!

Answer (score -1):

Another missing from this (oldish) list:

### [djangopypi](https://github.com/benliles/djangopypi)

It is Django based, which might be a slight overkill, but I love Django and it makes it extremely simple to modify it to your need should it not be satisfying.

Answer (score -1):

And the *crate* source code is available, though documentation is, least that can be said, nonexistent:

**[Crate.Web](https://github.com/crateio/crate.web)**

It's a Django application providing a Python Package Index. It uses a couple of other packages from [the
Crate repositories](https://github.com/crateio), so you might be able to roll out your own version without Django.

I'm specifically thinking about a static one. I always thought there should be a very easy way to go explore directly some [preconfigured] repositories and shop cheese directly from my GitHub or [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) public and private repositories, with just a simple (gunicorn) process running.

Comment: Sorry just notice that @tilgovi answer was also speaking about the crate source repository, not only the live service at http://crate.io, though that's the one which is linked in the answer.