# What is a Python egg?

Tags: python, package, egg

I'm trying to understand how Python packages work.  Presumably `eggs` are some sort of packaging mechanism, but what would be a quick overview of what role they play and may be some information on why they're useful and how to create them?

Comment: `egg`s are deprecated as of 2021, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70019592/6474744) which mentions **wheel** files (with the `.whl` extension) instead.

Answer (score 619, accepted):

> *Note: [Egg packaging has been superseded by Wheel packaging.](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/)*

Same concept as a `.jar` file in Java, it is a `.zip` file with some metadata files renamed `.egg`, for distributing code as bundles.

[Specifically: The Internal Structure of Python Eggs](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/doc/formats.txt)

> A "Python egg" is a logical structure embodying the release of a
>   specific version of a Python project, comprising its code, resources,
>   and metadata. There are multiple formats that can be used to
>   physically encode a Python egg, and others can be developed. However,
>   a key principle of Python eggs is that they should be discoverable and
>   importable. That is, it should be possible for a Python application to
>   easily and efficiently find out what eggs are present on a system, and
>   to ensure that the desired eggs' contents are importable.
>
> The `.egg` format is well-suited to distribution and the easy
>   uninstallation or upgrades of code, since the project is essentially
>   self-contained within a single directory or file, unmingled with any
>   other projects' code or resources.  It also makes it possible to have
>   multiple versions of a project simultaneously installed, such that
>   individual programs can select the versions they wish to use.

Answer (score 146):

The `.egg` file is a distribution format for Python packages. It’s just an alternative to a source code distribution or Windows `exe`. But note that for pure `Python`, the `.egg` file is completely cross-platform.

The `.egg` file itself is essentially a `.zip` file. If you change the extension to “`zip`”, you can see that it will have folders inside the archive.

Also, if you have an `.egg` file, you can install it as a package using `easy_install`

Example:
To create an `.egg` file for a directory say `mymath` which itself may have several python scripts, do the following step:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "mymath",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages()
    )
```

Then, from the terminal do:

```
 $ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

This will generate lot of outputs, but when it’s completed you’ll see that you have *three* new folders: *build*, *dist*, and *mymath.egg-info*. The only folder that we care about is the *dist* folder where you'll find your `.egg` file, **`mymath-0.1-py3.5.egg`** with your default python (installation) version number(mine here: 3.5)

Source: [Python library blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/)

Comment: while the egg file is portable across operating systems, it should be notable that it contains compiled pyc code so an egg compiled with one python version (X.Y) is not compatible with other versions.

Answer (score 40):

**Disclaimer: egg is an abandoned format of python package, the tools to use eggs no longer exist.**

An egg is a python package. It's a zip archive containing python source files and/or compiled libraries.

The format is not well specified about what it must contain or how to make packages for different versions of python and different operating systems, that's one of the reasons it was replaced.

The format appeared around 2004 and was in-use until the mid 2010s, it's been completely replaced by `wheels` and `pip install`.

Eggs were installed by the command `easy_install`. The command was removed in setuptools v58.3 (year 2021). You can no longer use eggs.

If you see anything that mentions `easy_install` or `egg`, be it any stack overflow answers or tutorials, it is seriously obsolete.

Recommend this longer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897551/5994461 for an in-depth history of python packaging. It's going over pip and wheels and eggs and much more.

Update: As of July 2023 the official python package repository pypi.org [no longer accepts upload of .egg packages.](https://blog.pypi.org/posts/2023-06-26-deprecate-egg-uploads/)

Comment: Had issues with .egg while working, .whl worked as expected and really fast. Thanks for the heads up, wish this information was easier to find.

Comment: "the tools to use eggs no longer exist" is a false statement.  For example, pyspark accepts egg files but not wheels. (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html)

Comment: that documentation is seriously obsolete. the commands to install eggs have been removed from the python interpreter, as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

"Egg" is a single-file importable distribution format for Python-related projects.

["The Quick Guide to Python Eggs"](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs) notes that *"Eggs are to Pythons as Jars are to Java..."*

Eggs actually are richer than jars; they hold interesting metadata such as licensing details, release dependencies, etc.