# `ModuleNotFoundError` When Importing Python Package from Git

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm attempting to install a `featurestore` package from a private GitHub repo via ssh with the following command:

```
pip3 install -U git+ssh://git@dsghe.<mydomain>/bshelton/package_test.git@master#egg=featurestore
```

The install is successful, per the image below:
[image]

But when trying to run `from featurestore import *`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'featurestore'` error.

Using `pip3 freeze`, I see that the package is installed, but not with the `<package>==<version>` syntax I would expect, but it seems to be referencing the git commit instead as its "version":

[image]

I believe that the repo's directory set-up is appropriate for a Python package, per the screenshot below.

[image]

A noticeable difference between this package's install and the other packages I've installed is that it seems like only the `...dist-info` folder is installed for my `featurestore` package, while every other installed package includes the actual package directory, in addition to the `...dist-info` folder. Using `ls ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`:

[image]

This is my first time, trying to create a package like this, and I've been referencing the several sources below, but would appreciate some insight from the community as to what I'm missing. Thanks.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

[pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Comment: Try the URL with `...#egg=featurestore` appended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835396/why-egg-foo-when-pip-installing-from-git-repo

Comment: @VPfB I still get the same results when specifying `#egg=featurestore` at the end. In addition to your link, I've been reviewing the following link too, and it seems like it should work. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#git

Answer (score 2):

The cause of my issue turned out to be a syntax error in my setup.cfg above the `package_dir` and `packages` lines, which are important if using a package layout with 'src'. Until I fixed the error, my package installed and imported fine in some contexts but not others

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve for this by moving my `featurestore` directory up one level, and getting rid of the `src` directory. Based on the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585246/pip-install-creates-only-the-dist-info-not-the-package), I may have been able to also solve for it by simply adding a `__init__.py` file directly in the `src` directory. But for my need, `src` was really an unnecessary level.

New package directory set-up:

[image]

Code ran in terminal:

```
!pip3 install -U git+ssh://git@dsghe.<mydomain>/bshelton/package_test.git@master#egg=featurestore
from featurestore.featurestore import *
```