# Deploy scrapy project

Tags: python, deployment, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to deploy scrapy project with scrapyd. I can run my project normally by use

```
cd /var/www/api/scrapy/dirbot
scrapy crawl dmoz
```

This is step by step I did:

1/ I run

```
scrapy version -v
>> Scrapy  : 0.16.3
lxml    : 3.0.2.0
libxml2 : 2.7.8
Twisted : 12.2.0
Python  : 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) - [GCC 4.6.3]
Platform: Linux-3.2.0-31-virtual-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
```

2/ install scrapyd with

```
aptitude install scrapyd-0.16
```

3/ I have project scrapy at /var/www/api/scrapy/dirbot (http://domain.com/api/scrapy/dirbot). I edit scrapy.cfg

```
[settings]
default = dirbot.settings
[deploy:scrapyd2]
url = http://domain.com/api/scrapy/dirbot/
username = vu
password = hoang
```

4/ I test with deploy command

```
scrapy deploy -l
>> scrapyd2             http://domain.com/api/scrapy/dirbot/
```

5/ But when I use command

```
scrapy deploy -L scrapyd2
>> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/settings/deprecated.py:23: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: You are using the following settings which are deprecated or obsolete (ask scrapy-users@googlegroups.com for alternatives):
    BOT_VERSION: no longer used (user agent defaults to Scrapy now)
  warnings.warn(msg, ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Scrapy==0.16.3', 'scrapy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 499, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1235, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 131, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 76, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/commands/deploy.py", line 76, in run
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

and

```
scrapy deploy scrapyd2 -p project
>> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/settings/d           eprecated.py:23: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: You are using the following settings            which are deprecated or obsolete (ask scrapy-users@googlegroups.com for alternat           ives):
    BOT_VERSION: no longer used (user agent defaults to Scrapy now)
  warnings.warn(msg, ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
Building egg of project-1358597244
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Deploying project-1358597244 to http://domain.com/api/scrapy/dirbot/addversio           n.json
Deploy failed (404):
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /api/scrapy/dirbot/addversion.json was not found on this se           rver.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at domain.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

* I don't understand what is python egg. Can you give me example about it? I don't know I had it or not. Maybe is that file /var/www/api/scrapy/dirbot/setup.py?

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = dirbot.settings']},
)
```

* How can I deploy my project. I don't know exactly did I do wrong, or miss a step?

Thanks

Comment: make sure the `url` is ok. Try the default `http://domain:6800`

Answer (score 1):

well from the error it seems that the web site you want to crawl give 404 error either you put the wrong web site or there is some configuration error.

about python egg, there is a good answer about that, check it at [What is a Python egg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg)

about setup.py : as i know it was used for install a python application from source using command `python setup.py install`

**edit**: it seems i was got confused about the command `pip`, sorry about that

Comment: fix it thanks for the heads up, when I tried running `pip install setup`, pip will download a python app called setup not install from source