# What is the difference between pip and conda?

Tags: python, pip, ipython, package-managers, conda

I know `pip` is a package manager for python packages. However, I saw the installation on IPython's website use `conda` to install IPython.

Can I use `pip` to install IPython? Why should I use `conda` as another python package manager when I already have `pip`?

What is the difference between `pip` and `conda`?

Comment: Reading carefully the [install page](http://ipython.org/install.html) you'll see [full instruction](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html) to install with pip and that `conda`/`enpgk` is targeted at `new users who want to get up and running with minimal effort` : canopy/anaconda are standalone environement, that do not interfere with system python (like venv but more powerfull). BTW IPyhton, not iPython (upper case I)

Comment: One difference is that many more things can be installed by pip than by conda:  pip can install anything from pypi in one command.  conda requires three commands: skeleton, build, install and possibly more if that doesn't work.  pip can install anything from github or source in one command.  conda requires writing a "recipe", which is not easy, especially since the documentation always seems to be incorrect/outdated.

Comment: Related question: What are the ADVANTAGES of pip over conda? I see lots of Anaconda advocacy below, but nothing for pip. Why is pip still the standard, if anaconda is so great?

Comment: I find this quote enlightening: "*Pip* is a package manager, and *Virtualenv* is an environment manager. *Conda* is both." ([ref.](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html))

Comment: Observation: I used to think conda implied downloading a zillion packages,  but this is apparenlty no longer true: you can install miniconda, which seems to essentially be just the package manager, https://conda.io/docs/install/quick.html

Comment: **Note:** The comment by @endolith is no longer accurate, things aren't that horrible ;)

Comment: @AMC conda can install things from pypi easily now?

Comment: @endolith conda can install from many repos now, pypi, conda-forge, npm repos, github, and many others.

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD How do you install from pypi?

Comment: @endolith You install conda and pip inside your conda environment, and then type "activate your_conda_env_name", then "pip install your_pip_package_name".  This will safely install pip packages from pypi inside your conda environment, and put them safely in the conda environment's package index so that conda can track them and do the environment integrity checking that pip cannot do (since pip is not an environment manager).

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD So that's not really "conda can install", it's "pip inside an environment can install"?  And you need `conda install conda pip` first?

Comment: @endolith Yes, that is correct.  If you want to use conda and pip together safely, then create a new conda environment with conda and pip packages installed in it, e.g., use ```conda create --name myenv python==3.9 conda pip```.  Then activate ```conda activate myenv```, and then you can use pip install.  Conda is aware of the pip-installed packages, and will still update packages that it installs, but it will not update the pip-installed packages.

Answer (score 740, accepted):

Quoting from the [Conda blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20170415041123/www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/python-packages-and-environments-conda):

> Having been involved in the python world for so long, we are all aware of pip, easy_install, and virtualenv, but these tools did not meet all of our specific requirements. The main problem is that they are focused around Python, neglecting non-Python library dependencies, such as HDF5, MKL, LLVM, etc., which do not have a setup.py in their source code and also do not install files into Python’s site-packages directory.

So Conda is a packaging tool and installer that aims to do more than what `pip` does; handle library dependencies *outside* of the Python packages as well as the Python packages themselves. Conda also creates a virtual environment, like `virtualenv` does.

As such, Conda should be compared to [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) perhaps, another tool that lets you handle both Python and non-Python installation tasks.

Because Conda introduces a new packaging format, you cannot use `pip` and Conda interchangeably;  `pip` cannot install the Conda package format. You can use the two tools side by side (by installing `pip` with `conda install pip`) but they do not interoperate either.

Since writing this answer, Anaconda has published a [new page on *Understanding Conda and Pip*](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/), which echoes this as well:

> This highlights a key difference between conda and pip. Pip installs Python packages whereas conda installs packages which may contain software written in any language. For example, before using pip, a Python interpreter must be installed via a system package manager or by downloading and running an installer. Conda on the other hand can install Python packages as well as the Python interpreter directly.

and further on

> Occasionally a package is needed which is not available as a conda package but is available on PyPI and can be installed with pip. In these cases, it makes sense to try to use both conda and pip.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'm still confused, however, with whether can Conda replace pip? i.e., can Conda do all what pip can do?

Comment: @lazywei: I don't think it can; it doesn't look like Conda supports the wheel archive format, for example. They have different aims.

Comment: Thanks. So I should follow the package's installation instruction to decide which tool should I use, right?

Comment: Also, it's *really* easy to install any python package (that uses setuptools) from source in conda. Just create a [recipe](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html), and `conda build`, and it will create a re-usable package that you can share with others via binstar or similar.

Comment: @naught101 "Just create a recipe"  That's not as easy as typing `pip install`.

Comment: Can some explain to me what would happen if you used pip and conda to install the same package except with different version, which would python use when you import them?

Comment: Everything created by `conda` screams at you not to use `pip`, since you'll break things. I would stick to one or the other.

Comment: There was something I was wondering about, regarding conda and its scope of work, considering distro/OS level package managers. If conda is language agnostic, why use conda instead of something like pacman? Is it just to decouple your python environment from distro updates? I find that kind of bizarre because in C/C++ compiler suites and libraries are managed through package managers, why is Python any different? Why is the distro "trusted" to manage C/C++ libraries but not Python libraries?

Comment: @jrh: you can't install multiple versions of the same package side by side when using the OS package manager, not as a core feature. Conda manages *environments*, each with their own mix of installed packages at specific versions. So project A, having been developed some time ago, can still cling on to an older version of library Foo (no resources available to upgrade the project to work with a newer release) while project B requires the newest version of the same library.

Comment: @jrh: and yes, you can do the same by compiling the library from source, locally, or by putting shared objects for specific versions in specific locations and some per-project config to keep them apart, but when you have to do this on different OSes and for a lot of different projects, suddenly having something like Conda manage this *for* you, with precompiled packages at the ready, becomes really attractive. Especially when the devs are really data scientists, not software engineers.

Comment: Good point, distro package managers don't (usually) allow for multiple versions installed side by side. I guess this is a design difference between the Python package manager and the linux package manager, the former tolerating duplicate library versions at the cost of increased disk usage, and the latter assuming that the distro's library version "just works" for all software that has a dependency against libX?

Comment: (If I'm getting too far off track at this point, I apologize), IIRC part of the reasoning behind a typical distro's package management setup (i.e., limited version specification support for dependencies) was to make it so that security updates could be easily rolled out; if a software application specifies an environment containing something like.... <ssl library> version X, and then a severe vulnerability is discovered, wouldn't that mean that most users would be stuck with that old version of that library indefinitely?

Comment: @jrh: conda aims to give you a dev environment, not a complete OS. You are yourself responsible to take care of security issues. The same is true when using pip, or when manually managing versions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does that mean that suppose, I've installed `keras` using `conda` to run my python code on Ipython Nb then do I need to install `keras` using `pip` so that it runs on a  simple .py file run in terminal.

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi: IPython is an environment built with Python, and run with a Python interpreter. If you installed IPython to run with your Conda python, then no, you don't need to use `pip` if you already used `conda` to install Keras.

Comment: So, that means installing a python library in anaconda simply means that I can run the `.py` file in the terminal without using `pip install library` again to run it on my terminal. Right?

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi: provided that you then use the Python executable that's part of the Anaconda installation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And how do I ensure that?

Comment: Conda 4.6 introduced experimental interop with non-conda-installed python packages. Some more details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623633/2127762. Pip has always recognized python packages that conda has installed, because conda packages include relevant metadata (`.egg-info` or `.dist-info` directory, etc.).  Saying one cannot use pip and conda interchangeably is probably overstated. It works best to create a python environment first with conda (which by default includes pip), and then use pip as a second step. You can still operate on the environment with conda after pip has mutated it.

Comment: @kalefranz: you can't just replace `conda` with `pip`, so they *still can't be used interchangeably*. No overstatement there.

Comment: Why did Ananconda not just extend pip?

Comment: @Phil: how would you even do that, when Anaconda manages software at a level that sits above the Python binary that would be needed to run pip? Conda manages the Python binaries, and can also manage environments without Python installed in it, so without pip too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point and that makes sense. I was thinking about them in of what consumers see (packages installed) and not how they work internally.

Comment: I feel like some of the content in this comment section would make a nice FAQ somewhere, maybe in a tag wiki? The [conda] wiki is looking [a bit bare](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/conda/info)

Comment: In this conversation thread above, people are using "conda" and "Anaconda" as though they are interchangeable.  They are completely different things in reality.  conda is an open source Python package.  conda is independent of Anaconda.  conda is and owned and maintained by the conda open source community.  Anaconda is a commercial software organization distributing the Anaconda Python distribution.  Please keep these distinct.

Answer (score 304):

**Disclaimer**: This answer describes the state of things as it was a decade ago, at that time pip did not support binary packages. Conda was specifically created to better support building and distributing binary packages, in particular data science libraries with C extensions. For reference, pip only gained widespread support for portable binary packages with wheels (pip 1.4 in 2013) and the [manylinux1](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) specification (pip 8.1 in March 2016). See the [more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897551/5994461) for more history.

Here is a short rundown:

### pip

- Python packages only.
- Compiles everything from source. **EDIT: pip now installs binary wheels, if they are available.**
- Blessed by the core Python community (i.e., Python 3.4+ includes code that automatically bootstraps pip).

### conda

- Python agnostic. The main focus of existing packages are for Python, and indeed Conda itself is written in Python, but you can also have Conda packages for C libraries, or R packages, or really anything.
- Installs binaries. There is a tool called `conda build` that builds packages from source, but `conda install` itself installs things from already built Conda packages.
- External. conda is an environment and package manager.  It is included in the Anaconda Python distribution provided by Continuum Analytics (now called Anaconda, Inc.).

conda is an environment manager written in Python and is language-agnostic.  conda environment management functions cover the functionality provided by venv, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv, and other Python-specific package managers.  You could use conda within an existing Python installation by pip installing it (though this is not recommended unless you have a good reason to use an existing installation).  As of 2022, conda and pip are not fully aware of one another package management activities within a virtual environment, not are they interoperable for Python package management.

In both cases:

- Written in Python
- Open source (conda is BSD and pip is MIT)
- Warning: While conda itself is open-source, the package repositories are hosted by Anaconda Inc and have restrictions around commercial usage.

The first two bullet points of conda are really what make it advantageous over pip for many packages. Since pip installs from source, it can be painful to install things with it if you are unable to compile the source code (this is especially true on Windows, but it can even be true on Linux if the packages have some difficult C or FORTRAN library dependencies). conda installs from binary, meaning that someone (e.g., Continuum) has already done the hard work of compiling the package, and so the installation is easy.

There are also some differences if you are interested in building your own packages. For instance, pip is built on top of setuptools, whereas conda uses its own format, which has some advantages (like being static, and again, Python agnostic).

Comment: pip no longer builds everything from source.  If a wheel is available, `pip install --use-wheel <package>` will install a built package.  See here: http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.  However my personal experience with wheel is that so few scientific wheel packages are available that it is purely academic.  And of course pip install mostly doesn't work either on windows if your build environment isn't set up exactly right.  So at the moment, conda ftw.

Comment: Wheels are still new, and not used by default, so it's not surprising that there aren't really many of them yet. Wheel still fits into the category of "Python specific", though, meaning it can be a poor fit for non-Python packages, or Python packages that depend on non-Python packages.

Comment: For an idea of the kind of things you can use conda to handle, checkout out https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes. Also, this answer leaves out the fact that conda is an environment manager as well, whereas with pip you have to fall back to something horrible like virtualenv.

Comment: I had to downvote this: the second bullet point is just a historical note now, but you go on it later on too. The main difference these days is that pip is a package manager while conda is more of an environment manager.

Comment: @Shep you mean the compiling thing? Pip still compiles from source. Conda never compiles from source. Part of the core philosophy of conda is that it leaves the potentially difficult compilation step to the package maintainer. And it's absolutely NOT true that conda is not a package manager. I suppose you don't think that apt or brew are package managers either. One should think of conda as a package manager like those (it can install any kind of package, not just Python), except unlike those it doesn't require root, works on any OS, and has environment support.

Comment: It's true that pip can compile from source but this is becoming less and less frequent as more package move to wheel: these days I can install most of what I need in a few seconds with pip. So it's not that this answer is wrong, it's just becoming slightly outdated as pip has improved quite a lot in the last few years

Comment: I also agree that conda has a package management component, but it's a lot more than that with the environment management it does. Conda is great if you want to use it as a tool to manage your whole workflow, but if you want something lightweight to integrate with an existing project it's a bit overkill.

Comment: It has ***never*** been true that pip can only install from source. Before wheels we had eggs as the default binary install format and the recommended distribution format for Windows installations, and pip would (and still will) install eggs if that’s the best available option.

Comment: For Windows developers, this answer is still quite up to date as per July 2020. I tried to install [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html) with pip and, after bumping against `cmake` and `make` commands that my Windows 10 system could not find, I had to revert back to Conda, which did everything for me. IMHO, the key takeout from [asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161801/asmeurer) is this: "_Part of the core philosophy of conda is that it leaves the potentially difficult compilation step to the package maintainer_"

Comment: The answer has some wrong information:  "External. Conda is the package manager of Anaconda, the Python distribution provided by Continuum Analytics, but it can be used outside of Anaconda too. You can use it with an existing Python installation by pip installing it (though this is not recommended unless you have a good reason to use an existing installation)."  conda is separate from Anaconda.  conda should be installed FIRST, and then pip installed inside conda, not the other way around.

Comment: Why some tutorials mix both pip and conda install methods?
For example here
https://dev.to/aws-builders/sagemaker-lifecycle-configurations-for-custom-environments-51k6

Comment: regarding the last edit. conda is not free or independent, it is largely developed by Anaconda Inc. and the package repositories are hosted by Anaconda Inc.  The community alternative (conda-forge) is also hosted by Anaconda Inc. There's an interview where the Anaconda CEO says conda-forge costs them $100 000 a month to host. They could change the terms of service anytime.

Comment: @user5994461 What you say is flat out wrong.  conda is free and open source.  See https://github.com/conda for details.  All packages on conda-forge are free to individuals to download and use.  Learn more at: https://conda-forge.org/#about   Some conda-forge licenses may not be embedded without paying royalties, that is why you should pay attention to licenses before embedding them in products.  Anaconda, Inc. distributes bundled conda packages with their Anaconda Navigator distribution, but that is completely separate from the conda FOSS package and environment manager.

Answer (score 119):

The other answers give a fair description of the details, but I want to highlight some high-level points.

pip is a package manager that facilitates installation, upgrade, and uninstallation of **python packages**.  It also works with virtual **python** environments.

conda is a package manager for **any software** (installation, upgrade and uninstallation).  It also works with virtual **system** environments.

One of the goals with the design of conda is to facilitate package management for the entire software stack required by users, of which one or more python versions may only be a small part.  This includes low-level libraries, such as linear algebra, compilers, such as mingw on Windows, editors, version control tools like Hg and Git, or *whatever else requires distribution and management*.

For version management, pip allows you to switch between and manage multiple **python** environments.

Conda allows you to switch between and manage **multiple general purpose environments** across which multiple other things can vary in version number, like C-libraries, or compilers, or test-suites, or database engines and so on.

Conda is not Windows-centric, but on Windows it is by far the superior solution currently available when complex scientific packages requiring compilation are required to be installed and managed.

I want to weep when I think of how much time I have lost trying to compile many of these packages via pip on Windows, or debug failed `pip install` sessions when compilation was required.

As a final point, Continuum Analytics also hosts (free) [binstar.org](https://binstar.org) (now called [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/)) to allow regular package developers to create their own custom (built!) software stacks that their package-users will be able to `conda install` from.

Comment: Per your final point, the [third-party **conda-forge** project](https://conda-forge.org) has rapidly become the industry-standard approach to publishing Anaconda packages. [We recently published several conda-forge-hosted packages](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/betse) for [our multiphysics biology simulator](https://gitlab.com/betse/betse) – and cannot recommend the process enough. There's a GitHub PR-based peer review component to submitting new recipes to conda-forge, but the advantages in terms of conda-forge automation strongly outweigh the upfront time investment. *Bam!*

Comment: @CecilCurry I've imported `Keras` in my code, installed anaconda on my mac and Keras is both `conda` installed and `pip` installed. So, when running my code in terminal, how do I know which `keras` is being imported(the `pip` one or the `conda` one)?

Comment: @Caleb Hattingh this is a great answer!  Getting the things compiled on Windows requires a deep knowledge Visual Studio.  Using conda removes almost all of that (often extreme Microsoft-specific) technical expertise to get the scientific libraries compiled without much effort.  conda is a god-send for that.  BTW, Anaconda is mostly out of the picture when it comes to conda, except as one of the maintainers, and a big contributor to the conda open source package.

Comment: @asn to see which package manager installed a package in a condo environment, type "condo list" and the listing will show you the source channel (conda-forge, anaconda, pypi or other repo) from which a package was installed.

Answer (score 58):

**(2021 UPDATE)**

TL;DR Use pip, it's the official package manager since Python 3.

### pip

- **basics**
- pip is the default package manager for python
- pip is built-in as of Python 3.0
- Usage: `python3 -m venv myenv; source myenv/bin/activate; python3 -m pip install requests`
- Packages are downloaded from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/), the official public python repository
- It can install precompiled binaries (wheels) when available, or source (tar/zip archive).
- Compiled binaries are important because many packages are mixed Python/C/other with third-party dependencies and complex build chains. They MUST be distributed as binaries to be ready-to-use.
- **advanced**
- pip can actually install from any archive, wheel, or git/svn repo...
- ...that can be located on disk, or on a HTTP URL, or a personal pypi server.
- `pip install git+https://github.com/psf/requests.git@v2.25.0` for example (it can be useful for testing patches on a branch).
- `pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.9.0%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl` (that wheel is Python 3.9 on Linux).
- when installing from source, pip will automatically build the package. (it's not always possible, try building TensorFlow without the google build system :D)
- binary wheels can be python-version specific and OS specific, see [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) specification to maximize portability.

### conda

- **You are NOT permitted to use Anaconda or packages from Anaconda repositories for commercial use, unless you acquire a license.**
- Conda is a third party package manager from conda.
- It's popularized by [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/), a Python distribution including most common data science libraries ready-to-use.
- You will use conda when you use anaconda.
- Packages are downloaded from [the anaconda repo](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/).
- It only installs precompiled packages.
- Conda has its own format of packages. It doesn't use wheels.
- `conda install` to install a package.
- `conda build` to build a package.
- conda can build the python interpreter (and other C packages it depends on). That's how an interpreter is built and bundled for anaconda.
- conda allows to install and upgrade the Python interpreter (pip does not).
- **advanced**
- Historically, the selling point of conda was to support building and installing binary packages, because pip did not support binary packages very well (until wheels and manylinux2010 spec).
- Emphasis on building packages. Conda has extensive build settings and it stores extensive metadata, to work with dependencies and build chains.
- Some projects use conda to initiate complex build systems and generate a wheel, that is published to pypi.org for pip.

### easy_install/egg

- **For historical reference only. DO NOT USE**
- egg is an abandoned format of package, it was used up to mid 2010s and [completely replaced by wheels](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/).
- an egg is a zip archive, it contains python source files and/or compiled libraries.
- eggs are used with `easy_install` and the first releases of pip.
- `easy_install` was yet another package manager, that preceded pip and conda. It was removed in setuptools v58.3 (year 2021).
- it too caused a lot of confusion, just like pip vs conda :D
- egg files are slow to load, poorly specified, and OS specific.
- Each egg was setup in a separate directory, an `import mypackage` would have to look for `mypackage.py` in potentially hundreds of directories (how many libraries were installed?). That was slow and not friendly to the filesystem cache.

Historically, the above three tools were open-source and written in Python.
However the company behind conda updated their Terms of Service in 2020 to prohibit commercial usage, watch out!

**Funfact**: The only strictly-required dependency to build the Python interpreter is zlib (a zip library), because compression is necessary to load more packages. Eggs and wheels packages are zip files.

### Why so many options?

A good question.

Let's delve into the history of Python and computers. =D

**Pure python packages have always worked fine with any of these packagers. The troubles were with not-only-Python packages.**

Most of the code in the world depends on C. That is true for the Python interpreter, that is written in C. That is true for numerous Python packages, that are python wrappers around C libraries or projects mixing python/C/C++ code.

Anything that involves SSL, compression, GUI (X11 and Windows subsystems), math libraries, GPU, CUDA, etc... is typically coupled with some C code.

This creates troubles to package and distribute Python libraries because it's not just Python code that can run anywhere. The library must be compiled, compilation requires compilers and system libraries and third party libraries, then once compiled, the generated binary code only works for the specific system and python version it was compiled on.

Originally, python could distribute pure-python libraries just fine, but there was little support for distributing binary libraries. In and around 2010 you'd get a lot of errors trying to use `numpy` or `cassandra`. It downloaded the source and failed to compile, because of missing dependencies. Or it downloaded a prebuilt package (maybe an egg at the time) and it crashed with a SEGFAULT when used, because it was built for another system. It was a nightmare.

This was resolved by pip and wheels from 2012 onward. Then wait many years for people to adopt the tools and for the tools to propagate to stable Linux distributions (many developers rely on `/usr/bin/python`). The issues with binary packages extended to the late 2010s.

For reference, that's why the first command to run is `python3 -m venv myvenv && source myvenv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` on antiquated systems, because the OS comes with an old python+pip from 5 years ago that's buggy and can't recognize the current package format.

Conda worked on their own solution in parallel. Anaconda was specifically meant to make data science libraries easy to use out-of-the-box (data science = C and C++ everywhere), hence they had to come up with a package manager specifically meant to address building and distributing binary packages, conda.

**If you install any package with `pip install xxx` nowadays, it just works.** That's the recommended way to install packages and it's built-in in current versions of Python.

Comment: OP asks about "Conda" not "Anaconda". This answer could be improved by better distinguishing Anaconda and the rest of the Conda ecosystem, specifically it gives a wrong impression of licensing. For example, the `conda` software is BSD3 and all Conda Forge packages have permissive licensing (BSD3 on recipes; original licenses on software). The linking of "*the anaconda repo*" to specifically the Conda Forge channel is misleading - anaconda.org hosts many channels and only the `anaconda`, `main`, `r`, and `free` channels fall under the restricted Anaconda licensing.

Answer (score 35):

Not to confuse you further, 
but you can also use pip within your conda environment, which validates the general vs. python specific managers comments above.

```
conda install -n testenv pip
source activate testenv
pip <pip command>
```

you can also add pip to default packages of any environment so it is present each time so you don't have to follow the above snippet.

Comment: I thought this was not recommended?

Comment: It's fully recommended to use pip inside of conda.  It's better to install using conda, but for any packages that don't have a conda build, it's perfectly acceptable to use pip.

Comment: nit: seems like the phrase would be `fully supported`? `fully recommended` implies, better to use pip than conda, within a conda enviornment, to my mind,a nd I'm not sure that is what you/they mean?

Comment: @HughPerkins what this means is that you should install pip inside your conda environment and use pip in that conda environment (only) when conda-formatted packages are not available from the major conda repos (like conda-forge or anaconda.org).  Use pip install LAST to maintain the environment integrity, since pip does not do environment package integrity checking after it (greedily) installs packages.  For more information see:  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

Comment: I switched to pyenv in the end. After several years of dealing with eternal pip vs conda conflicts it was sooo relaxing to just use pip for everything, and everything just works. (Like, pyenv handles the ability to have multiple python versions on your system easily, which virtualenv doesn't directly handle for you; but also lets you simply do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and similar)

Answer (score 34):

Quote from [Conda for Data Science](https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-data-science) article onto Continuum's website:

> **Conda vs pip**
>
> Python programmers are probably familiar with pip to download packages from PyPI and manage their requirements. Although, both conda and pip are package managers, they are very different:
>
> - Pip is specific for Python packages and conda is language-agnostic, which means we can use conda to manage packages from any language
>     Pip compiles from source and conda installs binaries, removing the burden of compilation
> - Conda creates language-agnostic environments natively whereas pip relies on virtualenv to manage only Python environments
>     Though it is recommended to always use conda packages, conda also includes pip, so you don’t have to choose between the two. For example, to install a python package that does not have a conda package, but is available through pip, just run, for example:

```
conda install pip
pip install gensim
```

Comment: This was what I needed, previously i have installed the package in pip but I am unable to import it in my conda environment. This helped to solve the issue.

Comment: You should install pip inside your conda environment and use pip in that conda environment (only) when conda-formatted packages are not available from the major conda repos (like conda-forge or anaconda.org).  Use ```pip install your_package``` LAST to maintain the environment integrity, because pip does not do environment package integrity checking after it (greedily) installs packages.  For more information see:  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

Answer (score 26):

`pip` is a package manager.

`conda` is both a package manager and an environment manager.

Detail:

[image]

Dependency check

> Pip and conda also differ in how dependency relationships within an environment are fulfilled. When installing packages, pip installs dependencies in a recursive, serial loop. No effort is made to ensure that the dependencies of all packages are fulfilled simultaneously. This can lead to environments that are broken in subtle ways, if packages installed earlier in the order have incompatible dependency versions relative to packages installed later in the order. In contrast, conda uses a satisfiability (SAT) solver to verify that all requirements of all packages installed in an environment are met. This check can take extra time but helps prevent the creation of broken environments. As long as package metadata about dependencies is correct, conda will predictably produce working environments.

References

- [Understanding Conda and Pip](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/)

Comment: I wonder what exactly is this "dependency check", pip is checking dependencies compatibility. `ERROR: package-a 0.5.9 has requirement package-b~=0.2.0, but you'll have package-b 1.0.1 which is incompatible.` (much faster than conda).

Comment: The table is helpful, but the "can require compilers" line is a bit ambiguous. Conda can install a package that itself requires a compiler; the various flavors of the Stan probabilistic computing language are examples (e.g., PyStan). In this case, Conda will install a platform-specific compiler if necessary, e.g., llvm for macOS.

Comment: "This check can take extra time..." I've literally waited over a weekend for an environment to be 'solved' (but ultimately wasn't). The solver doesn't scale well with number of dependencies: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11919

Answer (score 23):

Quoting from [Conda: Myths and Misconceptions](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/) (a comprehensive description):

...

### **Myth #3: Conda and pip are direct competitors**

**Reality: Conda and pip serve different purposes, and only directly compete in a small subset of tasks: namely installing Python packages in isolated environments.**

Pip, which stands for **P**ip **I**nstalls **P**ackages, is Python's officially-sanctioned package manager, and is most commonly used to install packages published on the Python Package Index (PyPI). Both pip and PyPI are governed and supported by the Python Packaging Authority (PyPA).

In short, pip is a general-purpose manager for Python packages; conda is a language-agnostic cross-platform environment manager. For the user, the most salient distinction is probably this: pip installs python packages within any environment; conda installs any package within conda environments. If all you are doing is installing Python packages within an isolated environment, conda and pip+virtualenv are mostly interchangeable, modulo some difference in dependency handling and package availability. By isolated environment I mean a conda-env or virtualenv, in which you can install packages without modifying your system Python installation.

Even setting aside Myth #2, if we focus on just installation of Python packages, conda and pip serve different audiences and different purposes. If you want to, say, manage Python packages within an existing system Python installation, conda can't help you: by design, it can only install packages within conda environments. If you want to, say, work with the many Python packages which rely on external dependencies (NumPy, SciPy, and Matplotlib are common examples), while tracking those dependencies in a meaningful way, pip can't help you: by design, it manages Python packages and only Python packages.

Conda and pip are not competitors, but rather tools focused on different groups of users and patterns of use.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really true, beyond a market positioning perspective.  For example, look at pytorch, which offers three types of install: conda, pip, source, http://pytorch.org/ , and recommends: conda

Comment: "Installing Python packages in isolated environments" is kind of the main thing most Python developers use pip for.

Comment: @Nick isn't it when the developer is already in 'that' virtual environment? I think pip works in virtual environment and installs package as if it's installing for a system.But as sanchos.s said, it installs only python packages and doesn't take care for the underlying libraries.  anyone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The linked document is interesting, but also an exhaustive read and in parts quite questionable. It seems to be written by someone with high experience in conda, but less experience in how PyPA packaging is used, so it feels a bit biased. For example the "Where to Go from Here" for PyPI is crazy. Mandating publishing through recipe feedstocks driven by some authority is a big limitation. It would complicate the publishing process, completely undermine release automation, break countless existing use cases, and would be very time taking to get off the ground. A revolting suggestion.

Answer (score 13):

**For WINDOWS users**

"standard" packaging tools situation is improving recently:

- on pypi itself, there are now 48% of wheel packages as of sept. 11th 2015 (up from 38%  in may 2015 , 24% in sept. 2014),
- the wheel format is now supported out-of-the-box per latest python 2.7.9,

"standard"+"tweaks" packaging tools situation is improving also:

- you can find nearly all scientific packages on wheel format at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs,
- the mingwpy project may bring one day a 'compilation' package to windows users, allowing to install everything from source when needed.

"Conda" packaging remains better for the market it serves, and highlights areas where the "standard" **should** improve.

(also, the dependency specification multiple-effort, in standard wheel system and in conda system, or buildout, is not very pythonic, it would be nice if all these packaging 'core' techniques could converge, via a sort of PEP)

Answer (score 6):

To answer the original question,
For installing packages, PIP and Conda are different ways to accomplish the same thing. Both are standard applications to install packages. The main difference is the source of the package files.

- PIP/PyPI will have more "experimental" packages, or newer, less common, versions of packages
- Conda will typically have more well established packages or versions

An important cautionary side note: If you use both sources (pip and conda) to install packages in the same environment, this may cause issues later.

- Recreate the environment will be more difficult
- Fix package incompatibilities becomes more complicated

Best practice is to select one application, PIP or Conda, to install packages, and use that application to install any packages you need.
However, there are many exceptions or reasons to still use pip from within a conda environment, and vice versa.
For example:

- When there are packages you need that only exist on one, and the
  other doesn't have them.
- You need a certain version that is only available in one environment

Answer (score 4):

> > Can I use pip to install iPython?

Sure, both (first approach on page)

```
pip install ipython
```

and (third approach, second is `conda`)

> You can manually download IPython from GitHub or PyPI. To install one
>   of these versions, unpack it and run the following from the top-level
>   source directory using the Terminal:
>
> ```
> pip install .
> ```

are [officially recommended ways to install](https://ipython.org/install.html).

> > Why should I use conda as another python package manager when I already have pip?

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307405/1587329):

> If you need a specific package, maybe only for one project, or if you need to share the project with someone else, conda seems more appropriate.

Conda surpasses pip in ([YMMV](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ymmv))

- projects that use non-python tools
- sharing with colleagues
- switching between versions
- switching between projects with different library versions

> > What is the difference between pip and conda?

That is extensively answered by everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers highlight the targets and benefits of pip/conda, it may also be of interest to point out their problems from a packaging perspective.

---

The main problem with pip is that common C extension libraries aren't shared between multiple packages. This means bindings packages have to build and bundle their whole extension dependency tree, which isn't elegant. It consumes more disk space than necessary, and security fixes for base libraries can't be managed from a top level, but need to be assessed for each extension package separately.

---

Conda, on the other hand, works at sysroot level and can share libraries across language boundaries.
While this is a great idea, conda packaging has many problems in practice. IMHO this is not due to a fault in the principle, but in the implementation of conda.

Conda follows a packaging model where not the actual project authors publish to the main channel, but instead packaging is done using "recipe feedstocks" managed by a third party.
This means updates have to be done manually, and newer or less popular packages will often not be available. Many packages are not regularly updated, so builds may be missing and the head version outdated.
Further, third-party packaging can in some cases lead to a degradation of quality (e.g. ABI safety problems). It is the original authors who know best how to properly build/configure their package, not third parties.

Conda also causes a lot of packaging duplication due to lack of interoperability with PyPA style packages.
This seems unnecessary in principle - why could conda not just provide a compatibility layer that would allow to specify dependency on a PyPA package? All the metadata would be in there, just using different conventions. But the reality is conda doesn't, and there have been no real motions to change this for a long time.
However, this could greatly reduce the maintenance effort for pure-python packages, and be helpful for certain extension projects that would take a very significant effort to conda package.

Support for direct packaging from upstream projects is poor in general.
It is somewhat possible with custom channels, but badly since end users have to determine the individual channels and enable the whole channel tree manually. Moreover, the build tools seem to be slow and inflexible, being very centered around the feedstock use case and native hosts.

Another limitation of conda is that its environments concept cannot truly fix the ["Dependency hell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) problem. It does not enable you to address conflicts by installing multiple versions of a package in parallel in the same environment.

Virtual envs are a long-known concept and equally available in the PyPA world.
Nowadays pip also provides a full dependency resolver.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is for Python only

`conda` is only for Anaconda + other scientific packages like R dependencies etc. NOT everyone needs Anaconda that already comes with Python. Anaconda is mostly for those who do Machine learning/deep learning etc. Casual Python dev won't run Anaconda on his laptop.

Comment: simple explaination, but I was taught to go directly to Anaconda's website and download the Python 2.x or 3.x distribution. Why? > because it contains all packages that a student will need. Numpy, Scipy, matpliotlib, sklearn etc. This is exactly why there is a gap in understanding the finer fundamental details. Student

Comment: I know this is an old answer at this point, but what you've written about Conda/Anaconda seems completely false to me.

Comment: @Galapagos  Your answer is misleading and wrong.  Anaconda is one of several industry standard Python distributions.  conda is separate from Anaconda, but it used by Anaconda.  Also today "Anaconda is mostly for those who do Machine learning/deep learning etc. Casual Python dev won't run Anaconda on his laptop." is blatantly wrong and outdated.  Anaconda is the default for most kinds of analytics and data science work using Python today.

Comment: Artificial Intelligence and Large Language Models rely heavily on FOSS packages like PyTorch, Tensorflow, and other data science frameworks for developing and training models for new applications.  Many AI and data analytics packages  like JupyterLab are complex  mixtures of  Python, Javascript, HTML, Node.js, Javascript, SQL, and other languages.  Anaconda is not needed for any of these projects.  The conda tools are FOSS, (no payments ever to Anaconda).    What I love is that CONDA makes it all work together using only Python.  IT JUST WORKS!  Most power tools take a little time to master.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found one further difference of a minor nature. I have my python environments under `/usr` rather than `/home` or whatever. In order to install to it, I would have to use `sudo install pip`. For me, the undesired side effect of `sudo install pip` was slightly different than what are widely reported elsewhere: after doing so, I had to run `python` with `sudo` in order to import any of the `sudo`-installed packages. I gave up on that and eventually found I could use `sudo conda` to install packages to an environment under `/usr` which then imported normally without needing `sudo` permission for `python`. I even used `sudo conda` to fix a broken `pip` rather than using `sudo pip uninstall pip` or `sudo pip --upgrade install pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Artificial Intelligence and Large Language Models rely heavily on FOSS packages like PyTorch, Tensorflow, and other data science frameworks for developing and training models for new applications.

Many AI and data analytics packages like JupyterLab are complex mixtures of Python, Javascript, HTML, C, C++, Node.js, TypeScript, SQL, and other languages. Lately Go and Rust are bundled in some of these.  Anaconda is not needed for any of these projects. The conda tools are Free Open Source Software (FOSS), which means NO payments  to Anaconda EVER.

What I love is that CONDA makes it all work together using only Python. I don't have to use a complex compilation process to get it working.

IT JUST WORKS!

SPEED MATTERS. SIZE MATTERS.
The complaints about conda slowness are valid, especially when 100s of packages are involved. It can takes hours for complex or outdated packages to install in a new conda environment if you don't follow good practices.  It helps a lot to do a little up-front work to install outdated or non-mainstream packages first, so that conda determine the remaining packages required to match outdated but necessary packages.

ORDER MATTERS.
I ran into the ordering problem recently trying to reuse many AI packages that require OpenAI v0.28.1.  OpenAI released its v1.x series of total API rewrites that broke 100s of packages without warning or migration tools included beforehand. OpenAI released new breaking releases and bug fixes every few days. So rather than trying to change airplane engines after takeoff, it was better to use the stable v0.28.1 production release. We started by conda installing the OpenAI v0.28.1 first and then installing everything else, this fixed the problem in minutes with minimal effort.  Their suggested upgrade path requires an out-of-channel AI solution ("grit"), with a paid commercial license for large scale production use.  Now the onus is on OpenAI to provide a regular conda package for developers to upgrade their products. Until then developers can use v0.28.1 from conda-forge.   Order matters, as does orderliness.  the "conda search" command helps you figure which package is likely to be your bottleneck.

To address speed issues for solving complex conda environments, I have used Mamba.   Mamba is a C++ rewrite of the conda core solver that uses the full conda command set that I use. Mamba is usually just as fast as complex pip installs. The error reporting from mamba is better than pip, and it does result in catastrophic failures and damage to conda environments, like pip can cause without warning.  Mamba can be tricky to set up right now, because it requires a separate installation and the documentation is not very complete yet. IMHO, the Mamba installer must be provided as a regular conda package, not as a separate installation.

Most power tools take a little time to master.  It still amazes me that I can reuse the efforts of 100s of other developers in so many languages, with so little effort.