# How to install theano library on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, theano, deep-learning

In my machine learning course we are going to start using [theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#install), a very well known library for deep learning architectures. I all ready installed it with the following command:

```
$ pip install Theano
```

By the way, when i want to test if it installed correctly, the python interpreter can´t fin the module. I dont know if im installing it right. Reading the documentation i found [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), is it right to first install anaconda and then try to install again with `pip` theano?. Is this the right way to install this library on MAC OS X?. How can i install this library correctly in order to use theano succesfully?

Comment: You can use the python from anaconda, or many other python installation. Here is the link to mac specific installation: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#macos . There is some people that know more the mac in theano mailing list if you know get an answer here.

Comment: Thanks, so you recommend me to install theano with anaconda?. Is this a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Python with Homebrew and installing Theano with pip after that worked fine for me. I just needed to install nose after that to be able to run the tests.

```
brew install python
pip install Theano
pip install nose
```

I cannot help much installing the framework with Anaconda though.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda is indeed highly recommended for python libraries. In fact, Anaconda is not only for python in contrast to pip. You can read more here: [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

For installing Theano, I had already installed Anaconda. I just simply did:

`conda install theano`

Then, in Ipython, I successfully imported theano:

`import theano`

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing Theano in a virtual enviroment as oppose to installing it globally via sudo. The significance of this step is nicely described [here](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/). 
In your terminal window, do the following:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python2.7 theano-env
source theano-env/bin/activate
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/v0.1/requirements.txt
```