# I can't install Theano on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, python-3.x, theano

I'm trying to install Theano (and subsequently pylearn2) with Python 3.4 on my MacBookPro, with Mac OS X 10.10.5. I have Anaconda and I follow the instructions reported on Theano's documentation (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html). I have to use the sudo -H pip command and Theano gets downloaded, a Theano folder is created in anaconda and all the required dependencies satisfying the versions requisites. However, when i write the

> import theano

command in Python, I get (both in the terminal and in ipython-qtconsole) the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/**init**.py", line 44, in 
>       from theano.gof import \
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/**init**.py", line 38, in 
>       from theano.gof.cc import \
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 64, in 
>       from theano.gof import link
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 12, in 
>       from theano.gof.type import Type
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/type.py", line 14, in 
>       from theano.gof.op import CLinkerObject
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 31, in 
>       from theano.gof.cmodule import GCC_compiler
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 37, in 
>       from theano.gof.compiledir import gcc_version_str, local_bitwidth
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/compiledir.py", line 259, in 
>       in_c_key=False)
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/sitepackages/theano/configparser.py", line 237, in AddConfigVar configparam.**get**()
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 279, in **get**
>       self.**set**(None, val_str)
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 290, in **set**
>       self.val = self.filter(val)
>
> File "/Users/davidefloriello/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/compiledir.py", line 185, in filter_compiledir
>       " or listing permissions." % path)
>   ValueError: compiledir '/Users/davidefloriello/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.4.3-64' exists but you don't have read, write or listing permissions.

This last line is quite surprising since I'm the only admin. I gave a look at this other question [How to install theano library on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728255/how-to-install-theano-library-on-os-x) but I haven't found it very useful, as our Python versions are different and it seems to me that my problem is a bit less vague.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks a lot,

Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem was found reported [here](https://github.com/dnouri/kfkd-tutorial/issues/9). The solution, updated to account for different user, is:

> Try and remove that '/Users/davidefloriello/.theano/' directory and
>   run Python again without sudo.