# anaconda - graphviz - can't import after installation

Tags: anaconda, conda, graphviz

Just installed a package through anaconda (`conda install graphviz`), but ipython wouldn't find it.

I can see a graphviz folder in `C:\Users\username\Anaconda\pkgs`

But there's nothing in: `C:\Users\username\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages`

[image: still wouldn't work]

Comment: The key to understanding is that `conda install graphviz` does not do the same thing as `pip install graphviz`.  `conda install python-graphviz` does.  `conda install graphviz` installs the binaries, which is the same as downloading and installing GraphViz from their website.

Comment: @endolith Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

On conda:

First install

```
conda install graphviz
```

Then the python-library for graphviz `python-graphviz`

> `gv_python` is a dynamically loaded extension for python that provides
>   access to the graph facilities of `graphviz`.

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

There is also pydot package, which can parse and dump into DOT language, used by GraphViz

```
conda install pydot
```

Comment: this is a conda only solution, no pip needed. I like that

Comment: Now how did you come to know about this additional requirement i.e. 'python-graphviz' package and why didn't anaconda mark this as a dependency in first place?

Comment: I still get ```OSError: `pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz (https://www.graphviz.org/) and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH.```

Comment: Aha!  `conda install python-graphviz` does the same thing as `pip install graphviz`.  while `conda install graphviz` does the same thing as downloading binaries from the GraphViz website.

Answer (score 195):

The `graphviz` conda package is *no* Python package. It simply puts the graphviz files into your virtual env's `Library/` directory. Look e.g. for `dot.exe` in the `Library/bin/` directory.

<del>To install the `graphviz` **Python package**, you can use `pip`:
`conda install pip` and `pip install graphviz`.</del>

<del>Always prefer conda packages if they are available over pip packages. Search for the package you need (`conda search pkgxy`) and then install it (`conda install pkgxy`). If it is not available, you can always build your own conda packages or you can try anaconda.org for user-built packages.</del>

<del>**Update Nov 25, 2018**: There exists now a [`python-graphviz` package at Anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python-graphviz) which contains the Python interface for the `graphviz` tool. Simply install it with `conda install python-graphviz`.

(Thanks to [wedran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763367/wedran) and [g-kaklam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5576273/g-kaklam) for posting this solution and to [endolith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125507/endolith) for notifying me).</del>

**Update May 26, 2022**: According to [the pygraphviz website](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html), the `conda-forge` channel should be used: `conda install -c conda-forge pygraphviz` (thanks to [ian-thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509519/ian-thompson))

Comment: How do I install the graphviz python package then? (this one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz)

I thought the "conda install" was equivalent to "pip install", I'm new to anaconda though.

Comment: You can try to `conda install pip` and `pip install graphviz`.

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the purpose of using anaconda for installing python packages? or is it not its intended purpose in the first place?

Comment: Always prefer conda packages *if they are available* over pip packages. You can always build your own conda packages or you can try http://anaconda.org/ for user-built packages.

Comment: @WolfgangUlmer your comment should be the answer

Comment: This answer helps to resolve some of the confusion I am having.  But I am trying to install pygraphvis (which is needed to use the `graphviz_layout` method of NetworkX).  So what is the difference between pygraphvis and the graphviz python package?  Presumably they are not the same thing.

Comment: @WolfgangUlmer just though I'd give a shout out to you for the use conda over pip packages. Wasted so much time until I realized that :/

Comment: `Always prefer conda packages if they are available over pip packages` Yes, so don't follow this answer.  Follow wedran's answer of `conda install python-graphviz` instead.

Comment: the pygraphviz site recommends installing from the `conda-forge` channel [source](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html)

Comment: I have tried the different solutions proposed here. In particular `pip install graphviz` and (separately, on a fresh env) `conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz`. None work worked for me. Is `python-graphviz-0.20.1` broken?

Answer (score 18):

for me the problem was solved by installing another supportive package.

so I installed graphviz package through anaconda 
then I failed to import it

after that I installed a second package named `python-graphviz` also through anaconda

then I succeeded in importing `graphviz` module into my code

I hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 12):

You can actually install both packages at the same time. For me:

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz python-graphviz
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

To install graphviz,

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
pip install graphviz
```

If conda command not found. Follow these:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
conda --version # to check your conda version
```

Difference between conda and pip installation,
refer this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Answer (score 3):

I have followed the following steps and it worked fine for me.

1 . Download and install graphviz-2.38.msi from
    https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

2 . Set the path variable

```
(a) Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings >  Environment Variables > Path > Edit

(b) add 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin'
```

Comment: This solution worked for me in trying to get `bprofile` installed on Windows, as it only searches in `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` for an installed graphviz/`dot.exe` and fails to find it if it's installed anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Graphviz is evidently included in Anaconda so as to be used with pydot or pydot-ng (both of which are included in Anaconda). You may want to consider using one of those instead of the 'graphviz' Python module.

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu users I recommend this way:

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, it reports that graphviz is already installed...

Answer (score 2):

Remeber！ If you are using jupyter notebook, please restart it after the installing. That's work for me.

Because the condition before is a static variate as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check if tensorflow is activated in your terminal

first deactivate it using

```
conda deactivate
```

then use the command

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

and then install

```
conda install graphviz
```

this is solution for ***UBUNTU USERS*** :) CHEERS :)

Answer (score 1):

This command works officially for python:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
```

Answer (score 1):

run this:
conda install python-graphviz

Answer (score 0):

I am using anaconda for the same.

I installed graphviz using `conda install graphviz` in anaconda prompt.
and then installed  `pip install graphviz` in the same command prompt. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and worked for me.

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
pip install graphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone - this really helped me.

The following combination seemed to be enough (Macbook Pro M1; Monterey; Anaconda):

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz \
conda install -c anaconda pydot \
conda install -c anaconda python-graphviz
```