# Error while installing Graphviz on Anaconda (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dependencies, anaconda, graphviz

I tried to install `graphviz` on anaconda after getting error:

> Exception: "dot" not found in path.

So I did `conda install graphviz`, but received this error in the terminal:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>
> - fontconfig
> - freexl
> - graphviz
>
> Use `conda info <package>` to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: Just tested: `conda install graphviz` worked on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 for me.

Comment: Try `pip install graphviz` as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33433735/5276734

Comment: Hey so I already tried that but I still get the error in Anaconda:Exception: "dot" not found in path.