# Saving Graphviz decision tree plot using Scikit Learn DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I am able to generate a decision tree plot using graphviz, but when I try to save it (i.e., out_file)

I get the following error:

> CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Tsvg']' returned non-zero exit
>   status 1.

Here is my code:

```
# create plot for decision tree
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model, 
                                out_file='tree.dot', # this is what triggers the error
                                feature_names=X_test.columns,
                                class_names=['Active','Churned']) 

graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 

# view plot 
graph
```

The `out_file` argument is the one that triggers the error. I'm thinking that this should be a pretty easy solution, but I have not found an answer from my searches.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to reinstall the packages. For example, check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362780/cant-display-graphviz-tree-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a parameter **"out_file = None"** at the end of the **tree.export_graphviz()**.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on your answer?