# conda environment has module installed but it does not import

Tags: python, conda, python-venv

I have a `tensorflow` conda environment and wanted to use `graphviz` to visualize the network. I installed graphviz which can be seen here given the output `conda list >> tfenv.txt`:

[image: graphviz is in the environment]

However, if i try to import graphviz it does not show up in python:

[image: python does not import graphviz]

What gives? I have no idea how the library can be in the environment but does not import.

The environment lives in another home directory from mine (`sysadmin`). If I use that user then I can load the environment and it imports with no problem.

[image: now the import works]

Are there two environments? What is happening here? Do different users "use" the environments differently?

I believe this all occurred because the machine had anaconda installed in the home directory my user (john) but then someone (not me) decided to install it for all users in `opt`. This is why the sysadmin uses a different conda then the john user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [anaconda - graphviz - can't import after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation). I.e., you also need the Python interface, `conda install python-graphviz`.

Comment: Your answer is correct. However, there also was a conflict between two anaconda installations that eventually was fixed by deleting all anaconda installations and reinstalling one.