# conda installed some package but still ModuleNotFoundError when import this package

Tags: python-3.x, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've found the solution:[anaconda - graphviz - can't import after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation)

I want to use `graphviz` and follow the commend in https://anaconda.org/anaconda/graphviz

run following in terminal

`conda install -c anaconda graphviz`

However no matter in Jupyter Notebook, python or Pycharm to `import graphviz`, it always shows

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'`

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

PS:

1. when run `which python` in terminal: it return `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`, therefore I use anaconda environment by default. And I have only one environment in anaconda that is `root`.
2. when I run `conda list` in terminal, I can find this line :

`graphviz                  2.40.1               hefbbd9a_2`

3. I found a weird thing:

my `pip` and `conda` use the same environment:

run :`which pip`

get : `/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip`

run : `which conda`

get : `/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda`

However when I run `pip list`, I cannot find `graphviz` and many other packages which shows in `conda list`. For these packages show in `conda list` but not in `pip list`, I also cannot import them no matter in Jupyter notebook, python, pycharm etc. Why this happens?

Comment: This usually happens when the virtual environment is not enabled properly or the PYTHONPATH does not contain the path to your installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

After using "conda install attrs", other package installations are working fine without any http connection or ModuleNotFoundError errors. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I've found the reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation