# Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, graphviz, archlinux

I'm trying to use [graphviz](/questions/tagged/graphviz) in a [jupyter-notebook](/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook). And I've installed two packages. One using `pip install graphviz` and one using `pacman -S graphviz` in [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux).

But when I type `import graphviz` in the *Jupyte Notebook,* I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
```

Even when I type `python -m "import graphviz"` in the terminal, I get the same error:

[image: No module named graphviz]

I've seen the answers in this [thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation) but they're all about installing `graphviz` through `conda`. But I'm not using the *Jupyter Notebook* through [anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda).

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the terminal use -c option `python -c "import graphviz"`

Comment: @abhilb That works, but I'm still unable to use it in the notebook.

Comment: It might happen that you have 2 versions of python installed. Try using in Notebook: `!pip install graphviz` --user

Comment: @Christoffer what are you trying to do man.. he is using arch linux

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake..