# The Kernel freezes with the import of the libraries in Python

Tags: python, anaconda, graphviz, pydotplus

I use Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook and have installed the latest version of Python 3.9.4.

After installing Python and Anaconda (anaconda3), I proceeded to install some libraries via the following command `pip install pandas scikit-learn graphviz`, which however turned out to be unnecessary getting `Requirement already satisfied`.

This is the problematic code that is causing me problems:

In [1]:

```
# standard libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import pydotplus #<---------------------------------------------ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from math import log
from six import StringIO 
from graphviz import Source #<----------------------------------ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
import graphviz as gr #<----------------------------------------ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
#from IPython.display import SVG
#from IPython.display import display
#from IPython.core.display import SVG
from IPython.display import Image

%matplotlib inline
#%pylab inline
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif

# pca libraries
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
#import seaborn as sb

# kfold stratification libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# libraries for building classifiers
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier        
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  

# libraries for evaluation metrics
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 

from datetime import datetime
from os import system
#from simple_colors import *

import bisect
import time 
import sys

# import warnings filter
from warnings import simplefilter
# ignore all future warnings
simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

# elimination of the conversion warning
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import DataConversionWarning
simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DataConversionWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
```

In [2]:

```
#dataframe import
#command parameters:
#filepath_or_buffer : str, pathlib.Path, py._path.local.LocalPath or any object with a read() method (such as a file handle or StringIO) The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file ://localhost/path/to/table.csv
#na_values : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None, Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. 
#low_memory : boolean, default True Internally process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use while parsing, but possibly mixed type inference. To ensure no mixed types either set False, or specify the type with the dtype parameter. Note that the entire file is read into a single DataFrame regardless, use the chunksize or iterator parameter to return the data in chunks. (Only valid with C parser)

def loadData(path):
    dataset=pd.read_csv(path, na_values=['Infinity'],low_memory=False)
    
    return dataset
```

Initially, for some absurd reason, in the first part of the code, in correspondence of the arrows I get those errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
```

although the necessary libraries are already installed. For further verification, I ran the following commands from the terminal:

```
pip install graphviz
```

```
pip install pydotplus
```

And as I already expected, I get `Requirement already satisfied`

Nevertheless, I still tried to comment the code at the errors, but when I try to execute the first part (and later, also the second one), my Kernel freezes, displaying **In [*]:**

How to resolve this situation?

**UPDATE**:

If it can help someone to get to the solution and solve the problem, I realized that the Kernel freezes only after running the imports, that is only the first block of code. However, the problem remains unsolved, because I need to import these libraries for my code to work (and don't let the Kernel freeze).

Comment: Probably again a PATH issue, I think there are quite a few questions regarding this type of problems with python not finding dot.

Comment: I have read about PATH issues, but when installing this version, it didn't ask me to disable the PATH length limit. I tried downloading older versions as well, but this feature has been removed

Comment: Probably talking about something different, I'm talking about the system PATH. Did you restart your terminal?

Comment: Of course, but nothing has changed

Comment: Considering you have installed Anaconda, I would recommend installing packages using `conda` to avoid many installation and dependency problems.

Comment: @GuillaumeAnsanay-Alex also tried this solution, but it didn't help

Comment: Are you installing those libraries (`graphviz` or `pydotplus`) from command line, using Anaconda or running pip from Jupyter notebook? I recommend installing libs like `python -m pip install pydotplus` otherwise it may happen in some cases you are using `pip` from different environment. And when using jupyter notebook, I would try the installation right directly within this notebook - run `!pip install pydotplus`. Does anything of this help you?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by your default pip installation being different from the one jupyter is using. The following script should be run in jupyter and will generate and execute a command that can be used to install the packages with the correct version of pip.

```
import sys
import os

executable_path = sys.executable
print(executable_path)
command = f'"{executable_path}" -m pip install pandas scikit-learn graphviz pydotplus'
print(command)
# Uncomment the following line if you prefer to run the command yourself
# exit()
exit_code = os.system(command)
if exit_code == 0:
    print("success!")
else:
    print("failure!")
```

Answer (score 0):

First install Graphviz from this site: [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Add Graphviz to the environment variable "Path":

- Go to `Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables` and then find "Path" in the system variables box. Click on Path and click edit.
- Append `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to the end of the many paths that are already present in Path. Note, the path to Graphviz may be different for you so make sure to put the correct path. The folder "bin" should have many files including the dot.exe application.
- To check the install go to the command prompt and enter: `dot -V` this should return the version of Graphviz installed. For example, `dot - graphviz version 2.38.0`. If this does not work, enter set and look for the Graphviz path

After this open Anaconda Prompt and reinstall Graphviz using the command `pip install --force-reinstall graphviz`

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Anaconda seems to support only python3.8 as of today: [Anaconda Download page](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads)
   , so I suspect the python3.9 you installed first is conflicting somehow with the latest anaconda and python you installed and something got corrupted.
   **Soln:** **1 >** I suggest, you uninstall anaconda, remove the Anaconda3 folder from your `C:\Users\your_user_name\Anaconda3` path, now uninstall python3.9 also completely, remove them from the Environment variables also. **2 >**  Now, just download the latest anaconda from the above url and when it asks you during install whether to add python3.8 to your path, please select the checkbox. **3 >** Next install the required packages from conda in the anaconda3 command prompt.
2. I have checked on SO and it seems like there is a problem with the pip version of graphviz. Please check the answer here: [Graphviz - Can't import after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33433735/9197808) they seem to have found an alternative package called `python-graphviz`.

Hope these help to solve your problem.