# Better way to distribute python command line applications

Tags: python, pip, py2exe

I want to understand the difference between distributing a python application. The application should be used on both Windows and Mac OS platforms. I see there are two ways of doing it.

1. Either create a executable using py2exe / py2app etc
2. Distribute the application using pip.

I would like to understand the use-cases for both the solutions.

Comment: You can simply google these. The answers to your question are well-documented all over the Web. If you want to share the source code, go with pip. Otherwise, use the rest.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. As Sam Chats mentioned, one possible use case for creating the executable is if you don't want to share your source code, while if you distribute the application using pip, you will be able to. Additionally, if you distribute using pip vs. creating an application, more users may be able to easily access your application. As an example, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068985/what-is-the-advantage-of-pip-over-anaconda) StackOverflow answer as a reason for using pip over Anaconda

Comment: My question was not about pip vs anaconda. I want users to use my command line on both Windows and MacOS platforms. I'll update the question with this.