# Updating ipython - jupyter giving internal server error

Tags: python, jupyter

I just upgraded my ipython (version 0.13.2, so quite old)

```
conda update ipython
```

then installed jupyter

```
pip install jupyter
```

When I now start a notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get an internal server error, and an error stack on the console that seems to boil down to

```
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/templates/tree.html", line 8, in template
    data-base-url="{{base_url | urlencode}}"
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'url encode'
```

Any ideas of what I did wrong/how to fix this?

Comment: This has been answered in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121163/4383027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall jupyter with conda, remove pip installed jupyter:

```
pip uninstall jupyter
```

And install jupyter with conda:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Comment: Thanks. In my desperation I did a `conda update --all` and that seems to have fixed it. What's the difference between pip and conda though? I thought both would upgrade necessary dependencies etc?

Comment: Checkout answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda