# Jupyter Notebook 500 Internal Server Error- No previous solutions work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, internal-server-error

With every jupyter notebook I'm launching, I'm getting the error "500 : Internal Server Error".

I have looked through all the previous answers to this question, but I am still getting the same error.

My notebooks were working yesterday, so I find this error very odd.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1590, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3006, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/config/handlers.py", line 19, in get
    self.finish(json.dumps(self.config_manager.get(section_name)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/config/manager.py", line 25, in get
    recursive_update(config, cm.get(section_name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 103, in get
    recursive_update(data, json.load(f))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

## The solution was to:

```
/.jupyter/nbconfig/
```

and edit the notebook.json file so that it looked like this:

```
{
  "load_extensions": {
    "jupyter-notebook-gist/extension": true,
    "jupyter-js-widgets/extension": true,
    "nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main": true,
    "contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main": true,
    "equation-numbering/main": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that's probably mis-configured kernel or something. I would recommend starting over.

Comment: As in uninstalling  and installing python?

Comment: probably best to create a new `virtual environment` or a new `conda environment`, and install fresh `jupyter`

Comment: Cheers. I have installed jupyter through pip, so I will try uninstalling it first, then try out anaconda.

Comment: This has been answered in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121163/4383027

Answer (score 0):

I faced to this error after I update Jupyter notbood

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32032254)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you can try:

Restart Jupyter Notebook
Upgrade jupyter package
You can use the following command to upgrade the Jupyter Notebook
pip3 install --upgrade --user nbconvert