# Jupyter-notebook "500 : Internal Server Error"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to open jupyter notebook in anaconda but I got a 500 : Internal Server Error.

I tried all the solutions from

[Jupyter Notebook 500 : Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851746/jupyter-notebook-500-internal-server-error)

I also tried

```
pip install update pygments
```

finally I uninstall and install anaconda but it still doesn't work.

Error message:

```
[E 19:45:02.700 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Untitled.ipynb (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebook\handlers.py", line 101, in get
    get_frontend_exporters=get_frontend_exporters
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 507, in render_template
    return template.render(**ns)
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "page.html" %}
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
    {% block header %}
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\notebook.html", line 114, in block "header"
    {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebook\handlers.py", line 23, in get_frontend_exporters
    from nbconvert.exporters.base import get_export_names, get_exporter
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .exporters import *
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .html import HTMLExporter
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\html.py", line 15, in <module>
    from nbconvert.filters.markdown_mistune import IPythonRenderer, MarkdownWithMath
  File "C:\Users\m\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\filters\markdown_mistune.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_lexer_by_name' from 'pygments.lexers' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Have u tried installing it in the same conda env ?

Comment: Do you mean jupyter notebook? I have installed it on the same env.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening here is that you have created an environment, and installed pygments with `pip install pygments`. However, I think you forgot to also install jupyter in that env (`conda install jupyter`). In that case, conda falls back to your `base` env which does have jupyter but probably not pygments. In the *same* environment you have pygments install you should have jupyter installed.

I would go ahead and do the following:

```
conda create --name YourEnvNameHere python=3.6 jupyter pygments ... any_other_package_you_need
```

Then,

```
conda activate YourEnvNameHere
```

and then type

```
jupyter notebook
```

to launch a jupyter notebook on your localhost.

Comment: I tried, didn't work for me. I have never install pygment before the error happens, it is preinstalled when I set up the env