# Jupyter notebook error while saving / pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a problem while trying to save my jupyter notebook.

It shows:

```
Unexpected error while saving file: notebook.ipynb HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Couldn't save the `notebook)`
```

My Code:

```
# Read in dataset
import pandas as pd
apps_with_duplicates = pd.read_csv("datasets/apps.csv")

# Drop duplicates from apps_with_duplicates
apps = apps_with_duplicates.drop_duplicates()

# Print the total number of apps
print('Total number of apps in the dataset = ', len(apps))

# Have a look at a random sample of 5 rows
n = 5
apps.sample(n)
```

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

[Jupyter Notebook 500 : Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851746/jupyter-notebook-500-internal-server-error)

Especially mikus answer:

```
$ pip install --upgrade jupyterhub
$ pip install --upgrade --user nbconvert
```

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36852617/16063775

```
sudo pip install --upgrade "ipython[all]"
```