# "500 : Internal Server Error" when trying to convert .ipynb to .py

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to convert a jupyter notebook I have to a .py file, but I keep getting `500 : Internal Server Error`. I'm able to open the notebook, run it in my browser (Chrome), and save output .jpeg and .csv files without any trouble. When doing `jupyter notebook`, I get the following output in my terminal:

```
[W 17:53:56.505 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `ExporterCollapsibleHeadings`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.533 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `TocExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.550 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.566 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.601 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.604 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.740 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsSlidesExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.808 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:56.812 NotebookApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsLatexExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 17:53:57.241 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js (::1) 6.230000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/SBU_Research/ProtoDUNE_DP_VD_PMT_Analysis.ipynb
```

This is concerning, but I don't know if it's an issue.

I've tried upgrading to the most recent version of nbconvert (and other proposed solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851746/jupyter-notebook-500-internal-server-error)), but this does not fix the issue. Below is the entire error message from my terminal:

```
[E 17:54:56.110 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /nbconvert/script/Desktop/SBU_Research/ProtoDUNE_DP_VD_PMT_Analysis.ipynb?download=true (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/nbconvert/script/Desktop/SBU_Research/ProtoDUNE_DP_VD_PMT_Analysis.ipynb?download=true', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 537, in get
        value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
    KeyError: 'template_paths'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
        yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/nbconvert/handlers.py", line 92, in get
        exporter = get_exporter(format, config=self.config, log=self.log)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/nbconvert/handlers.py", line 67, in get_exporter
        Exporter = get_exporter(format)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 101, in get_exporter
        if getattr(exporter(config=config), "enabled", True):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 341, in __init__
        super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 117, in __init__
        self._init_preprocessors()
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 507, in _init_preprocessors
        conf = self._get_conf()
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 525, in _get_conf
        for path in map(Path, self.template_paths):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 577, in __get__
        return self.get(obj, cls)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 540, in get
        default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1580, in trait_defaults
        return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 977, in __call__
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 536, in _template_paths
        template_names = self.get_template_names()
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 620, in get_template_names
        raise ValueError(
    ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'script' found in the following paths:
        /Users/jacob/Library/Jupyter
        /Users/jacob/Library/Python/3.9/share/jupyter
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/share/jupyter
        /usr/local/share/jupyter
        /usr/share/jupyter
[E 17:54:56.114 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/SBU_Research/ProtoDUNE_DP_VD_PMT_Analysis.ipynb",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
[E 17:54:56.114 NotebookApp] 500 GET /nbconvert/script/Desktop/SBU_Research/ProtoDUNE_DP_VD_PMT_Analysis.ipynb?download=true (::1) 36.000000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/SBU_Research/ProtoDUNE_DP_VD_PMT_Analysis.ipynb
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I'm also open to feedback on how I've formulated/formatted my question. I've been using Stack Overflow for some time, but this is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

**you could open it on colab and it will be available for download as py file** [image]

Comment: This is a great workaround, and I'm able to use Google Colab to get a .py file. But this doesn't solve the underlying issue. I'd ideally like to not rely on Google Colab (and an internet connection). It's my understanding that since jupyter notebooks execute locally, converting .ipynb to .py would not require an internet connection. If that conversion does require an internet connection, using Google Colab seems to be as good as it gets. Thanks, @omar!

Comment: Maybe "pip install --upgrade jupyter" fix the issue give it a try

Comment: more info in question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851746/jupyter-notebook-500-internal-server-error)