# "500 : Internal Server Error" response while opening any notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I had problems opening my jupyter notebook so I deleted it and downloaded it again, but now every time I try to open a notebook "500: internal server error" appears on my screen. I have already tried upgrading jupyter and I have an assignment pretty soon where I have to use jupyter notebook so help is really appreciated!

I have already tried upgrading jupyter, which did nothing noticeable.I have an assignment pretty soon where I have to use jupyter notebook so help is really appreciated!

Comment: Potentially duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851746/jupyter-notebook-500-internal-server-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying and pasting an answer that I found [here](https://github.com/d2l-ai/d2l-book/issues/46) and worked for me. Install this:

jinja2==3.0.3

nbconvert==6.4.4

with pip you can use this command:

```
pip install jinja2==3.0.3 nbconvert==6.4.4
```