# How to replace pip with conda?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, anaconda, conda

My package on PyPI depends on numpy, which is notorious for failing after `pip install mypackage`.  I would like to replace `pip` with `conda` as a tool for installing my package.  What are the steps for preparing a package to be deployed from Anaconda instead of PyPI?

I imagine at least the following steps are involved:

- host `mypackage` on a conda channel
- `conda install -c https://my_channel/mypackage`

Comment: have a look into this discussion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-condahttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: I know the difference.  Many thanks.  I'm looking for guidance on how to transfer the deployment workflow over to Anaconda.  To my knowledge, this has not been clearly addressed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build your package as a conda package and then upload it to the anaconda cloud.

[This](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/bpp.html?highlight=conda%20build) is the official documentation on how to build a conda package.  You will need a meta.yaml (describing your dependencies -- i.e. numpy, etc.), build scripts (build.sh and bld.bat depending on your environment -- build.sh will probably just call `$PYTHON setup.py install`), and then your setup.py and any of those other standard files (like MANIFEST.in).  The you will run `conda build` for your package to generate the conda package and put in some location call it `/path/to/YOUR-PACKAGE.tar.bz2`.

Once you have your package built you can upload it to your anaconda channel on the anaconda cloud.  First you will need an account.  Then you can [upload](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cloud/using#uploading-conda-packages).  Basically by doing:

```
anaconda login
anaconda upload /path/to/YOUR-PACKAGE.tar.bz2
```

Now people can install your package with something like  `conda install -c YOUR-NAME YOUR-PACKAGE`