# How to install library

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am a little bit confused....

I installed anaconda on my computer (I have windows 10).
Normally, when I want to install a package I simply do "`pip install package_name`" or "`conda install package_name`" and it is done.

> First question: what is the difference between pip and conda?

Now I tried to install xgboost and it was really complicated I tried lot of things nothings worked until I install something called miniconda.

There it works but now, when I do "`conda install package_name`" it install it in `miniconda3/lib/site _package` and I have to copy/paste it in `Anaconda3/lib/site_package` if I want it to work.

> Second question: how can I ask to the computer that "`conda install
>   package_name`" install it directly in anaconda3 and not miniconda3?

Finally I tried to install the package "surprise" for recommended systems. Both "pip install" or "conda install" failed.

I went in github and got the file "surprise" from https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise

I tried to copy it in Anaconda3/lib/site_package but it doesn't work.

When I do `from surprise import Reader` I did not get the error "`no module name surprise`" anymore but I get "`cannot import name 'Reader'`"

> Last question: how can I make it work? I think I have to build it but
>   I do not now how...

Thank you in advance for anyone that can explain all this for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to you, I had issues installing the surprise package.
I tried both `pip install surprise` and `conda install surprise` unsuccessfully.

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 scikit-surprise 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 scikit-surprise
```

I found those on the [anconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-surprise) website and the first one worked for me.

Hopefully this would help you as well

Answer (score 1):

**pip vs conda**

`pip` is a `package manage`r that facilitates `installation`, `upgrade`, 
and `uninstallation` of `python packages`. It also works with virtual python environments.

`conda` is a `package manage`r for any software (`installation, upgrade and uninstallation`).
 It also works with virtual system environments.

`Conda` is a `packaging tool` and `install`r that aims to do more than what `pip` does;
 handle library dependencies outside of the Python packages as well as the Python packages themselves.
 `Conda` also creates a virtual environment, like `virtualenv` does.

For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

**Anaconda vs miniconda**

The open source version of `Anaconda` is an `easy-to-install` 
high performance `Python` and `R` distribution with a `package manager`, 
environment manager and collection of 720+ open source packages.
 It also comes with the options to install `RStudio`.

The "lite" version of Anaconda without the collection of 720 packages.
The downside is that you need to type in command line commands, 
"conda install PACKAGENAME"

**And Last**

To install this package with conda run:

`conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost=0.60`

**Update for surprise**

The easiest way is to use pip (you'll need numpy):

```
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install scikit-surprise
```

Or you can clone the repo and build the source (you'll need Cython and numpy):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/NicolasHug/surprise.git
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thank you very muche for all those explanations.

Comment: Just one last question you might be able to help me with...

The package I want to install is "surprise" (to handle recommander systems)

I try to run:

- `conda install -c anaconda py-surprise` and I get `PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - py-surprise`

- `conda install -c anaconda surprise`  and I get

`PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - surprise

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    surprise: r-praise`

Comment: Thanks. The link which you provided for `surprise` in your question there was a `README.md `. And here is given installation and usage guide. Please follow that. and also got https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/issues/21