# python pip install to Anaconda directory

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter

I am configuring a brand new machine and have just installed Anaconda and python.

In the command line, I type in

```
pip install %PACKAGENAME%
```

When in a jupyter notebook, I type in:

```
import %PACKAGENAME%
```

It cannot find the package.

Turns out that when I type in sys.path, I get:

```
C:\\Users\\ywu\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\
```

Therefore, I have to specify the path first:

```
sys.path.append("C:/Users/ywu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages")
import %PACKAGENAME%
```

This step is unnecessarily annoying. There are two options, either:

1. automatically install into the Anaconda folder
2. automatically import from the python36-32 libraries

Can someone please advise on what is the best practice between 1 or 2 and how I can actually accomplish 1 or 2?

Comment: Is anaconda the only python you have installed? Do you have any other virtual environments installed as part of anaconda?

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is the only python I've installed and I do not believe I have any other virtual environments.

Comment: Why are you trying to use pip with Anaconda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: Habit I guess? I've used pip with my old machine and had no problems.

Comment: Did your old machine use Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda is an all-in-one environment and package manager. Pip has made some major strides forward in recent years due to pressure from anaconda being so good, so the two tools have feature parity.

On the command line, you can run

```
conda activate <env-name>
```

Then you can run

```
conda install <package-name>
```

For the most part, conda is just a proxy for pypi, so you get the exact same package as with pip.

Personally, I don't use anaconda anymore, and I just use pip. Anaconda is good for python web-dev because web projects are much pickier about dependency versions. I mostly use python for the scientific packages, and those are not as sensitive the version changes as web frameworks.

Comment: Anaconda is meant to be used for the scientific packages, though. It's overkill for web development

Answer (score 0):

You can save the folder with Anaconda in it within the same folder that the python file is in and then write something like

```
from whateverthefolderisinhere import Anaconda
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I appreciate that answer. However, I'd like to avoid having to do that as I will need to add that to every notebook.