# Difference between conda and pip installs within a conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, package-managers

I seem to be asking myself this question a lot, having recently switched to using conda environments (Anaconda), but I end up Googling and not getting too far.

I now run all my projects within their own conda environments, as I like to keep everything as separate and with as little dependencies on other programs as possible. For example, a recent environment:

```
conda create -n RL numpy tensorflow-gpu
```

Then I activate the environment, and realise "Oh - I forgot to install gym". In this case, this is only available in the PIP package manager, and so I simply type `pip install gym`. But in other cases, where the package exists within conda and pip, what is the best way to install it?

`conda install package`
`pip install package`

Or in other words - what is the difference?

To provide the full picture, I'm running everything in Ubuntu 16.04, and switch between python 2 and 3 depending on the project. So some of my conda environments are in python 2, some are python 3. I've found that sometimes a `pip3 install` is required for python 3, but not always - why is this?

Secondly, my path links to the python setup in my Anaconda3 directory.

My current idea is that if I install via `conda`, it installs directly to my environment, but via `pip` it installs to my anaconda3 site-packages, making it available to all conda environments under my Anaconda3 directory. If this is the case, this means that if I `pip install gym` in one conda environment, it should also be available in all others - but this isn't the expected behaviour of environments as far as I am aware.

Please feel free to correct my assumptions and knock some sense into me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Answer (score 3):

For my understanding of Conda that, it manages for you all the dependencies. For example if you have a package (like pandas) that requires another package (like numpy), it will download both (after warning you).

Where conda is becoming handy is that sometimes a specific package requires a specific version of another one (4.3 or later for example) and they can be conflicts between the packages. The requirements and conflicts define a mathematical problem that can be solved thanks to a SAT solver.

You can find informations and link about that here: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/new-advances-conda-0

So each time you are installing a new package, it will upgrade (or sometimes downgrade if conflicts) other packages to ensure the functionning of each package. Personnaly, I go with `conda` and use `pip` only when the package is not managed by `conda`

Another link if you are interested by conda: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/

About `pip3`, it is the naming used when you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, to avoid conflicts in the command. In a python 3 environment, the command `pip` will be equivalent to `pip3`.

For the behavior of `pip`, I can confirm that the installation is done only in the active environment and is not available to the other ones

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that conda will know about the new environment it created but pip will not. You need to install pip inside the environment.

If you create a new environment and activate it: e.g.

```
conda create -n env_name
source activate env_name
```

Then install pip using conda:

```
conda install pip
```

(gotcha warning) if you run `which pip` this should give the path to the pip installation in the new conda environment (something like this):

```
/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/pip
```

however, just running `pip install new_package` still does not seem to work, you need to explicitly reference the full path (e.g. [Tom Roth's blog post](http://www.puzzlr.org/install-packages-pip-conda-environment/)) when installing pip packages inside a conda environment

```
/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/pip install new_package
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know about earlier versions, but in `conda 4.7`, you can install `pip` packages inside a `conda` environment, without installing `pip` or referencing `pip` using its full path. You can also notice that `pip` is automatically installed when you create a new `conda` environment.