# In a Anaconda virtual environment，what‘s the difference between "conda install package_name", "pip install package_name"?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, caffe2

The default PyThon environment in my linux is: `Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`, I created the virtual environment: `Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

First, I enter the Aanconda virtual envirenment: `source activate python27`

Then, I installed caffe2, there is an error: `ImportError:No module named google.protobuf.internal`

so, I use conda to install protobuf: `conda install protobuf`, but the error still exists。
when I use `pip install protobuf`， the error disappeared.

What's the difference:

```
conda install package_name
pip install package_name
/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/bin/pip install package_name
apt install package_name
```

Is `pip install package_name` the same as `/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/bin/pip install package_name` ? When I `which pip`, it shows: `/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/bin/pip`

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/q/20994716/6673446

Comment: Also duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/45831255/6673446

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)