# Use conda or pip in intel-python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, intel, conda

Recently I installed `intel-python` distribution on my windows machine. I found that it supports `conda` and `pip` installs right off the start.
I tried using **both** and they seemed to work fine.

They both installed packages to the ***same***  python distribution, so I dont have much problem using any of them.

But I was wondering if one was better than other **in certain situations** or in **general**?

Comment: There is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: But this isn't really Anaconda. I am not sure what intel-python is doing in the background