# Keras not working with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, keras, ubuntu-16.04

When I trying to install keras with pip3 this message shows.

```
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from keras)
```

But I import keras in a project it shows this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

How to solve this problem? I used Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.

Comment: please mark if the answer solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a virtual environment? If so make sure to activate it.

**EDIT**: To expand on what "virtual environment" means, look [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html) and [here](https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) at "Conda."  Conda can help you with installations in many ways; it can help you update Keras later on, it will help you manage which packages you need with which Python scripts so you don't have to write a million `import numpy as np` statements everywhere, etc. etc.  There is a more in-depth, clear explanation of what Conda is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Also you can see what packages are installed with:

```
pip3 freeze
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is use keras in a separate environment using conda.
Suppose you want to create an env named "myenv" 
1.Open Anaconda promt and type the following:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

2.To activate the environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

3.Now you can install keras and other dependencies:

```
pip install keras
```