# ImportError: cannot import name 'msgpack'

Tags: python, pandas, dask, castra

I'm following a [tutorial](https://oikonang.github.io/Parsing-Reddit-Data-with-Dask/) that uses castra and dask to read in reddit comments.

I have installed the latest versions of dask and pandas using anaconda and castra using pip.  My pandas version is '0.22.0', and I have installed msgpack using `pip install pandas-msgpack -U` I am using Python 3.6.

Trying to import castra gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fcdf7be49118> in <module>()
     32 from pandas import Timestamp, NaT, DataFrame
     33 from toolz import dissoc
---> 34 from castra import Castra
     35 from toolz import peek, partition_all
     36 import time

/Users/edefilippis/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/castra/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .core import Castra
      2 
      3 __version__ = '0.1.7'

/Users/edefilippis/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/castra/core.py in <module>()
     22 import pandas as pd
     23 
---> 24 from pandas import msgpack
     25 
     26 

ImportError: cannot import name 'msgpack'
```

Comment: Note that castra is unmaintained: https://github.com/blaze/castra#maintenance

Comment: @MRocklin, shucks.  did not realize this.  what is the best alternative?

Comment: @MRocklin, oh wow!  Just realized you were the developer.  Great work

Comment: Probably the most common file format these days for dataframe storage is parquet, which has several of the features for which castra was designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://pandas-msgpack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html try:

```
conda install pandas-msgpack --channel conda-forge
```

as you might be missing some dependencies. Also see pip vs conda:

[What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Comment: Thank you.  I did this, and am still getting the same import errors

Comment: Only at SO can you get an answer by a developer at the package management system itself, i.e Anaconda. See MRocklin's answer above. Pretty awesome. @MRocklin