# Packaging with manylinux + auditwheel pip wheels vs. Conda

Tags: python, conda, python-wheel, conda-build, python-manylinux

## Description

So I am looking to package a fairly complex python application that requires scientific libraries. This question is somewhat similar to [the stackoverflow pip vs conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda) discussion but it does not go into detail about the differences now that binary packaging for linux wheels is available since 2016. I have seen that [pypi/cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography) uses manylinux and distribute binaries via pypi wheels. Another package mpi4py only releases for binary packages for conda only because of [the difficulty](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/96/linux-wheels-using-manylinux). Even going as far as to say that binary wheels are not appropriate for the task.

## Question

What does shared library packaging via wheels look like vs conda? Is shared library packaging via wheels even worth it as of 2018?

## Requirements

My package requires

- openblas
- fftw3
- openmpi
- [lammps](http://lammps.sandia.gov/)

In all the my static binary is about 100Mb so it does require a lot of shared libraries. And many I also point out that installation is a huge pain even for myself... I can't imagine what it would be like for someone trying to install it themselves. So far I have a working docker container.