# AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute '__module__'

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-image, numpy-ufunc

I have installed skimage using `'pip install scikit-image'` inside a conda environment. 
I am using `python 2.7`.

When I try importing :

> from skimage import transform

It gives me the error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute '**module**'

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It smells like the wrong versions of numpy going on. Which version of skimage do you have? What about numpy? (Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have mismatched version of scikit-image and numpy because of the recent updates in each of it's respective library. The correct version that I found works compatible with each other is `0.14.1` for scikit-image and `1.15.4` for numpy.

Install these specific version of libraries by executing these commands:

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
pip uninstall numpy
pip install scikit-image==0.14.1
pip install numpy==1.15.4
```

Now importing these libraries should work and produce no error.