# How to Install Geopandas on Windows 10 Using pip

Tags: python, pip, geopandas, osmnx

In the interest of having a working solution accepted on Stack overflow with as much info as possible on the issues that come up with using pip to install Geopandas or a package like OSMnx that depends on it using pip on Windows 10 I'll post my workflow below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible problems and they have to do with the difference between pip and conda discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

First, pip requires Visual C++ to compile packages, while conda does not.

The easiest way to ensure that you have Visual C++ available is to install the community distribution of [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). Depending on the options selected this is potentially several gbs so a good internet connection helps a lot.

Second, use pip to install the wheels of `GDAL` version 2.4 not 3.0, `Fiona` `Shapely` and possibly `Rtree`. These can be found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

If you have GDAL already installed via `OSGeoW64` you'll need to uninstall that by deleteing the entire OSGEo4w folder in the C: drive

Pick the version for the architecture of python that you have installed, NOT the architecture of your computer. Check using [this clever line](https://intelligea.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/check-if-python-version-is-64-or-32-bit/) that offers an indication of what the difference between architectures actually is.

```
import struct;print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8 )
```

Finally, you may need to set [environmental variables](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them). It's important to know that `gdal-config` and `GDAL_CONFIG` are specific to linux based OS's and for windows, you're looking for `GDAL_VERSION` and `GDAL_DATA`.

Be sure to `pip uninstall <package>` before installing from a wheel or otherwise, and be sure to actually import the packages before assuming that they have installed correctly, even if there weren't any error messages upon `pip install`

Lastly, there is a lot of helpful info already out there but not collected in a sinlge place so if there's something missing of course edit the answer to include.

edit: just tried this with a python environement using the 64bit version of python 3.7.4 and it also worked.

One note, initially, the install failed, `OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll`

To solve this and possibly other errors, `pip uninstall` and `pip install` the wheels for `numpy` `GDAL` `Rtree` `Shapely` and `Fiona` a second time. Either I did not install them in the correct order initially or their is a circular dependency that installing everything twice resolves.

edit: Stackoverflow just told me this q/a has over 1000 views while receiving 0 votes. I'm not concerned about the points or whatever but in the interest of having a working answer, if this doesn't work for you consider leaving a comment or adding an answer of your own.