# Can all 'pip' packages be installed through 'conda install' command?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, anaconda, python-packaging

I'm using a station without admin rights and without pip. I need to use PyCharm (already installed) so as a workaround I installed Anaconda Navigator (doesn't require admin) and am using an environment in Anaconda as my interpreter in PyCharm.

I'm a bit confused regarding the `conda install` and the packages offered there. Are they all the same as the ones offered by the Python Package Index? Do developers only upload their work once to pypi.org and then it appears on both `pip` and `conda` installations or does it not include every single python package out there?

Thanks and I apologize if the question doesn't belong to this section of stack exchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Answer (score 0):

First here is a link to an anther great post with a similar question: [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

But here is a response from my point of view and understanding:

Pip libraries specifically focus on packages related to the python. Conda uses those too, however, it also provides packages not related to python.

The best package example available is HDF5 it was not originally integrated into pip and Conda had their own hdf5 package. Pip has a similar package called h5py.

Also, conda's virtualization environments are what so appealing about it. In a way, Conda is like Docker.

Conda Hdf5: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/hdf5

Pip h5py: https://pypi.org/project/h5py/

Conda Cloud has the ability to read the PyPi libraries index, so it will be aware of newly uploaded packages.

Sorry if my response was not clear enough! English is not my first language, plus I was in the same boat as you a year ago.

Comment: However, I forgot to mention to be careful when you are using both conda and pip together. Pip cannot install what is available in the Conda Cloud, but pip can be installed via conda and used this way. 

Since if new package comes out on the PyPi which is not available in the Conda Cloud you can use conda installed pip. 

I made a huge mistake of using pip method to install the package into my root Anaconda environment and messed it up entirely to a point where I even had to delete .folder files manually.

Please if you can help improve my response, please do so. I appreciate feedback.