# No module called pylogit

Tags: python, installation, package, python-import

I am unable to find the pylogit package in python, when I run this "import pylogit as pl", I get back the error saying no module called pylogit. can you please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of what Code-Apprentice stated, you'll need to run the commands...
`pip install pylogit`, more info [here](https://pypi.org/project/pylogit/).
or...
`conda install -c timothyb0912 pylogit`, more info [here](https://github.com/timothyb0912/pylogit).
If you are unsure what command you should run, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda) is another stack overflow discussion about the differences between the pip and conda.

Answer (score 3):

`pylogit` is not a standard Python module. It is not installed by default. You need to install the library on your machine with a package manager like `pip` or `conda`.