# can't import Quandl module in python

Tags: python, module

I've installed quanld with `pip install quandl`command and it was successful. But when I tried to import it in VSCODE, it returns an error.

[image: mod]

Update: Installing quandl with pip.

[image]

and now trying to import but lowercase
[image]

but it doesn't work yet

Comment: Have you made sure that the python 3 version has quandl installed in it? Try ```pip3 install quandl```

Comment: Also would recommend you to try importing it by using ```import quandl``` Instead of the ```import Quandl```. Hope this helps.

Comment: try lowercase  quandl like  `import quandl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the lowercase works to import *Quandl* from version 3! Probably a change in the namespace from the previous versions as mentioned in the [Quandl Blog](https://blog.quandl.com/quandl-python-package-upgrade?utm_source=bing&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=&utm_content=tag/python).

```
import quandl
```

Also try to make sure you have it installed in the required python version in case your system has multiple versions of python installed.

```
pip3 install quandl
```

This works for python3.

If you have a virtual env setup, make sure you have the module installed inside the env!

Comment: As you can see in the terminal, I tried `import quandl` and `import Quandl` as far as I know it would be the second one. Anyway, I tried using pip3 (first I uninstall Quandl, and now I installed it) but the result is the same.

Comment: That's weird. It did work well in my case. But have you been able to check if you have a virtual environment running? And to check if quandl has been installed inside the virtual env?

Comment: I see, sorry for that and for my english. Also, I don't know how could I check if quandl is installed in the virtual env. I'm using one, (base, anocanda default enviorement) so I ran VSCODE from there, using `code` command. How could I check if quandl was installed?

Comment: No problem! And you could activate the virtual env in your command prompt and then run the ```pip3 install quandl``` command. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: If that does not work, I would suggest you try running ```conda install -c anaconda quandl ``` from your anaconda prompt.

Comment: Hello once again! It seems pip3 isn't a recognized command for anaconda prompt, however I tried with pip one, and it worked. Thanks a lot! just out of curiosity what is the difference between `conda install -c anaconda quandl` and `pip3 install quandl`? However, thanks once again.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda) has some good discussions about the difference. Hope this helps! Also if my answer did help, [don't forget to upvote and accept the answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Take for granted that I tried to upvote your answer before, but it seems I don't have enough privileges for that. (I don't use too much English stack overflow). The only thing I can do for now is to mark it as the correct one. I'm so sorry. and thanks once again.