# Python Packages - How and Where?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently entered into python environment, and installed Anaconda Distribution along with python(3.8.0) from python.org. Both are installed in different locations.

My queries regarding pip are:

1. If I do pip list (in my system) I get a certain packages - I want to know that whether these packages are installed through anaconda or python?
2. If I need to install new packages through pip where does it get installed (in python location or at anaconda), so that I can access from other applications?

Comment: Have you read through any Q&A's found searching with `python anaconda pip site:stackoverflow.com` (or variants)?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda) (old question a few newish answers)  ..

Comment: You could install something with pip then go look in `...\Python38\Lib\site-packages` to see if it showed up there.  Or try `pip list -v`

Comment: @wwii No, I didnt read Q&A's