# What does it mean that Conda and Pip cannot be used interchangeably?

Tags: python, pip, conda, package-managers

Some time ago, I installed Django (with `pip`) and had some trouble doing some things with it because I didn't create a virtual environment (at least that's what it looked like). That time I was recommended to install it with `conda` since I use Anaconda's spyder.

Now, with a new Windows installation, I'm trying to start to learn Django again, but I'm confused as to whether I should use `conda` or `pip` to install it. I read here [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda) that they cannot be used interchangeably, but I'm not sure what that means.

If I install Django and some other packages with `conda`, does that mean I have to do something extra to then install some package with `pip`? Say, if there is a package `conda` can't install, as I read in that same question.

They said that `conda` "also creates a virtual environment`, does that mean that every time I install something with it, it is not being installed globally and besides the installation I also set up its virtual environment?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `pip` merely installs python packages, whereas Anaconda manages entire python environments, as well as installs packages. You can install python packages in a conda environment with either `pip` or `conda`, but you can't really switch between python versions and environments with `pip`

Comment: @bug_spray To avoid repeating the same comment, please have a look at the one I added to the answer.

Comment: Not sure which comment you're referring to, but "they can't be used interchangeably" means "they're not the same thing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a `conda` package without *activating* an environment installs the package to `conda`'s default virtual environment, called `base`. I'd recommend you read up on how virtual environments work and prevent package conflicts.

You can install a python package in a `conda` environment using `pip`. Just activate that environment and use `pip install package_name` as you would normally do. You should however avoid this by first making sure the package is unavailable in any of the conda repositories.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the recommendation would be to install Django with conda and activate a virtual environment for each project? With the initial project being the one I'll use to learn the first things.

Comment: @TheSprinter exactly.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I'm seeing in the Anaconda documentation that to install a package, you use `conda install package-name`, but in the page for Django in the Anaconda repository, I see `conda install -c anaconda django`. What's with the `-c anaconda`?

Comment: `-c` specifies a channel from which the package is to be installed. Checkout https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html