# how do I update pandas library using conda in mac os?

Tags: pandas, anaconda

I installed anaconda in my Mac and it shows pandas version as 1.0.5. (using `conda list` )

I want to upgrade my pandas version. How can I do it using conda commands?

I tried `conda update pandas` but it shows me this

```
conda update pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 

Updating pandas is constricted by 

anaconda -> requires pandas==1.0.5=py38h959d312_0

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`

done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: Did you try `conda update pandas`?

Comment: yes i did but it shows the same version

Comment: @Erfan I have added my logs about the command u suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparentely the conda channel has net yet updated the default to the latest pandas version which is `1.1.0`, so we have specify the version:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas==1.1.0
```

Comment: can u let me know what conda-forge does? i hope it does not break other libraries

Comment: It;s one of the channels, it will not break anything.

Comment: cool thanks, can u also tell me how is `conda install` different from `pip install package-name` ?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Comment: That command just seems to run forever, has been 15 minutes so far, will it ever end? : % conda install -c conda-forge pandas==1.1.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems as you. This was my sequence of commands that was finally successful. It's not ideal to update everything, but it worked. Save this idea for a last ditch effort.

```
conda deactivate
conda update --all
```