# Several questions when we install pytorch with pip or conda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pytorch

When I install the tensorflow, they told me to inspect the Nvidia drive and So I did.

I install the Nvidia's drive on Nividia wibset. And when I input 'nvidia-smi' in CMD, it says " *CUDA Version：10.1* " So I thought the cuda was installed.but after I install tensorflow-gpu, it turns out that I did't have the CUDA. So I wonder **if the Nividia driver includs the "CUDA**" and **why the 'nvidia-smi' told me "CUDA Version：10.1" but I did't have one**.And **How do I confirm that CUDA is installed**.

Then I try to install the pytorch on the [Pytorch's website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). The course told me the best way to install is **using miniconda**, because **miniconda can install the cuda and cudnn automatically**. but I'm used to using the pip,and I wonder **if the pip can install the CUDA and cuDnn automatically ,just like miniconda**？ Then I start to download with pip,but I find it is so slowly. it will take me 20h.I used to replace the source of the PIP to install the numpy and so on, but I can't change [THE COMMAND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb72q.png)，So I have no idea about **how to accelerate it**.

When I install the pytorch with the pip command above, **it contains the CUDA unexpectly!**  I don't understand why!! But when I use 'nvcc -V' in CMD, It doesn't work!

Finnaly , if I install the pytorch-gpu  with conda or pip , when I install tensorflow, should I install "CUDA" and "cuDnn" again?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Comment: I am sorry but I really know about that anser.The bold font is my question, thank you!