# Which environment am I using? pip or conda?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, conda

```
pip install package-name
conda install package-name
```

I installed a package with pip and conda. When I import it in python, which one is I am using exactly? And how can I change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what environment you are using, and where you run the install commands! `pip` goes together with `venv`, or virtual environments. `conda` goes together with conda environments.

Basically, `pip` and `conda` are both package installers. `venv` and `conda` environments are used to seperate python projects which might have different dependencies (For example, different python projects could require different versions of `numpy` or `tensorflow`).

When you `import` a package, where things get imported from depends on which environment you activated, or to which interpreter your python shell/IDE is linking at the moment.