# conda packages ending with pypi - where do they come from?

Tags: python, conda, pypi

I'm trying to clone a conda environment. I tried `conda list --export` and then tried restoring into a new environment.

However, there were a lot of packages ending with `=pypi` that could not be found in conda's repository.

Where do these `=pypi` packages come from?

Comment: I guess they were installed using `pip` instead of `conda`

Comment: Looks like you're right? But how do I handle them?

Comment: By handle I mean install them / remove them from this list

Comment: `conda install pip && pip uninstall <packages> && pip install <other_packages>` See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20994716/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+%5Bpip%5D+using

Answer (score 0):

According to [Anaconda's Managing Environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) webpage, you can create a `yml` file and then create a new environment by using this `yml` file. The advantage being that "this file handles both the environment's pip packages and conda packages."

So firstly you create the `yml` file from the environment you want to clone (I'm using  Windows PowerShell as an example of the expected output in the terminal):

```
(base) C:\Users\user> conda activate envIWantToClone
(envIWantToClone) C:\Users\user> conda env export > myEnv.yml
```

This `yml` file will be in the directory of the terminal, i.e. `C:\Users\user`. Then you have to edit the first  line of the file, changing the name of the environment from `envIWantToClone` to `clonedEnv`, for example:

```yaml
# name: envIWantToClone  # CHANGE THIS TO clonedEnv
name: clonedEnv
channels:
 - defaults
 - cona-forge
dependencies:
...
```

Then back in the terminal (which environment is currently active does not matter at this point):

```
(envIWantToClone) C:\Users\user> conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Then check if everything is working correctly

```
(envIWantToClone) C:\Users\user> conda activate clonedEnv
(clonedEnv) C:\Users\user> |
```