# Why I can use 'pip' to install a python package but not 'conda'?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, conda

A bit nervous for the first time to asking on stackoverflow :D
I want to know the differece between 'pip' and 'conda' more deeply and comprehensively.

Here, I want to install a package named 'librosa' for my assignment purpose.
I used to use 'pip' to install all packages needed such as pytorch. But today I'd like to have 'conda' a try instead.
When I typed

```
conda install librosa
```

I encounter an error as below:[image]
I tried to modified the permission of this folder, but it didn't work.
Then I tried

```
pip install librosa
```

just as I did before. It works! Like this picture:
[image]
So, I want to know what causes this problems.
By the way, I also appreciate that you can provide some official tutorials or blogs.

Comment: No screenshots of text or code. Copy-paste the text or code into the question instead.

Comment: just type conda vs pip on google. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897551/7639622

Comment: You are using two different environments. One is is D and the other is in your C:\user. So you are not installing it on the same place. Note: you should avoid to install packages on plain system. Always enter in a virtual environment (or conda environment) (eventually just create one), and install packages inside such environments. Else you will have quickly problems (compatibility, etc.). A broken environment is better then a broken base.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have solved my problem. I find that I select "install anaconda for all users" when I installed anaconda. I reinstall it and solve the problem. Thank you a lot. :D