# Why does py not recognize all Python versions?

Tags: python

If I use `py -0`, I get:

```
 -V:3.11 *        Python 3.11 (Store)
```

But if I use `python -v`, I get:

```
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:39:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Why does py not recognize other Python versions? VS Code detects that I have 4 of them:
[image]

The result on cmd:

```
where python
C:\Users\ganuo\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\ganuo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe

where python3
C:\Users\ganuo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

Strangely it doesn't show the [Orange](https://orangedatamining.com/) path.

Answer (score 1):

Using `where` in cmd might help you

```
where python
where python3
```

Remove other versions and use the command

```
conda install python=3.11
```

`pip` and `conda` are two different package managers and do the same thing in a bit different ways and `pip` is Python specific whereas `conda` is not. You can get more info from [`SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda) or [`article`](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip)

`py` is a launcher of Windows which recognises all Python versions if it is setup installation to do so: -
*Install launcher for all users (recommended)*
[image: installer]
It seems that neither orange or conda does so. You can run them individually it is preferable to use the Store version or from the official site and check mark on *Install launcher for all users (recommended)*
Read: [`Docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) and [`article`](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3617292/how-to-use-pythons-py-launcher-for-windows.html) for details.

Comment: if I want to only use the latest version, what should I do to make sure all programs will run fine? Especially conda

Comment: Does `where python` and `where python3` show all of the versions of Python you have? If so you can use `python3` for `Python 3.11` and `python` for `Python 3.10`

Comment: I've updated the results in my post. Strangely it doesn't show the Orange path. Is there a way to have `python` to run 3.11, and tell config conda to use that as well?

Comment: would installing conda be the same with installing directly from the official page?

Comment: If your question is to install Anaconda from  the [`official page`](https://www.anaconda.com/download) then yes install conda if you don't have it already then install python by using `conda install -c anaconda python` to download the latest version of python as instructed [`here`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python)

Comment: no I mean the [official Python page](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Reading the [Known issues](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#known-issues "4. Using Python on Windows — Python 3.11.3 documentation") section for the MS package, I still don't see why `py` doesn't recognize it. In fact it only recognize that version, and ignore everything else