# Python traceback points to non-existent file

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a `setup.py` script (for [mnemosyne](http://mnemosyne-proj.org/)).  The script fails, and I'm pretty sure I know how to fix the problem, if I could only find the file to edit.  The problem is that the traceback points to a non-existent file:

```
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 49, in locate
    loader=loader.filename)
TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'
```

I believe that should be `loader_path`.  The problem is that `MachOGraph.py` file doesn't exist -- not anywhere in my current path, or in my anaconda distribution.  There is a `build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/` directory, but no `egg`.  There are a few `MachOGraph.py` files on my system, but none of them have that line.  Nothing under this directory contains the string `loader.filename`.

What's going on?  How can I find that file?

For completeness, here is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mike/.continuum/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb/__main__.py", line 157, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/Users/mike/.continuum/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/Users/mike/.continuum/anaconda/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "setup.py", line 241, in <module>
    app = py2app_app
  File "/Users/mike/.continuum/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/mike/.continuum/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/mike/.continuum/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/src/Mnemosyne-2.3.1/py2app-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 654, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/src/Mnemosyne-2.3.1/py2app-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 860, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/usr/local/src/Mnemosyne-2.3.1/py2app-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 950, in run_normal
    self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
  File "/usr/local/src/Mnemosyne-2.3.1/py2app-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 1110, in create_binaries
    platfiles = mm.run()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 105, in run
    mm.run_file(fn)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 84, in run_file
    self.scan_node(m)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 110, in scan_node
    m = self.load_file(filename, caller=node)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 93, in load_file
    newname = self.locate(name, loader=caller)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 23, in locate
    newname = super(FilteredMachOGraph, self).locate(filename, loader)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 49, in locate
    loader=loader.filename)
TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: **That is the problem**, the OP doesn't know how to locate that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python takes the filename *as reported in the bytecode* when printing a traceback. In this case, the bytecode contains filenames that are generated to produce a [Python egg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg), a format that contains at least the bytecode files. These paths reflect the build directory relative to the package as it was built.

In this case, it is the [py2app installer](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) that includes macholib as a installation requirement; setuptools downloads the [source code for that library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/macholib/) and produces an egg on demand, in the same location as the `py2app` egg. I'd look in `/usr/local/src/Mnemosyne-2.3.1/py2app-0.8.1-py2.7.egg` for a `macholib-1.6-py2.7.egg` directory.

Comment: `macholib` itself is definitely not anywhere in the source, or in anaconda.  Maybe it got downloaded and removed?  In any case, I installed `py2app` and `macholib` myself, then re-ran and it worked (in the sense that I got past that error).  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Mike: yes, it's not clear immediately where setuptools puts it when `py2app` is being installed in the `/usr/local/src/Mnemosyne-2.3.1`, I expected it to be located there too. There are environment variables that can be set, it could be installed in `/tmp` for all we know.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by *Pillow*, you can use `pip uninstall Pillow` to uninstall it, then this question will disappear.

Comment: I did not have Pillow installed.

Answer (score 0):

With *macholib1.7,* from line 46 of **/MachOGraph.py...:

```
            try:
                fn = dyld_find(filename, env=self.env,
                    executable_path=self.executable_path,
                    loader=loader.filename)
                self.trans_table[(loader.filename, filename)] = fn
            except ValueError:
                return None
```

**Change line 49 to:**

```
                    loader_path=loader.filename)
```