# How to package/distribute a multi-file python script as one package/module onto servers?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As a python noob, this might be an obvious question but just wondering if there's a way to package multiple python modules as one file and then copy it from server to server.

Basically, I wrote a script to be run on our servers.  Because it started getting large, someone asked me to break tasks out to different files, kind of like different java class files.  I have a main.py, download.py, process.py, etc.  In the main.py, at the top, I have all my import statements.

```
import main
import download
import blah
import etc
```

Now that I need to copy this script to multiple servers, I want to know if there's an easy way to package all these files into one package/module so I only have to copy one file, rather than multiple py files to each server.  Also, when making updates/changes, it will make things easier to manage too.

I ran into PyPI from Head First Python but I don't think we want to publish this script for all to see.  A non-Internet sharing way to package the files is appreciated  =)

Comment: http://mrtopf.de/blog/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg

Comment: http://pythonwheels.com