# Selenium Firefox webdriver results in error: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, exception, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a program that will search a website for specific entries inside of articles, I'm using selenium webdriver for Python.

While attempting to connect to the site I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most 
recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 26, in <module>
    test.search_for_keywords()
  File "search.py", line 13, in search_for_keywords
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2
```

It's saying that the webdriver unexpectedly exited. How can I fix this issue? I'm trying to connect with firefox version 48.0 with python version 2.7.12

Answer (score 6):

**Running python selenium tests in latest Firefox browser (Version 47 above)**

“Marionette" or "Gecko Driver” is the future version of firefox driver. Firefox 47+ is not compatible with the driver used in Selenium 2.53, and Selenium 3+ will be using a new driver called "Marionette" or "Gecko Driver" (which isn't officially released yet).

**Prerequisites:**

•   Mozilla firefox : Version 50.0.2(Version 47 above)

•   Selenium : Version 3.0.2

•   Geckodriver : Version 0.11.1

•   Python : Version 2.7.3

**Setup:**

•   Selenium : `pip install –U selenium`

•   Geckodriver : Download the geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases , unzip the file and place it in a folder

•   Set the ‘Path’ environment variable with geckodriver path

**Sample script:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
```

**#Provide the Firefox binary path**

```
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe’)

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
```

**#Set ‘marionette’ browser to True**

```
caps['marionette'] = True
```

**#Launch the Firefox instance by specifying the geckodriver executable path**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,capabilities=caps, executable_path`='D:/Installers/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver')
```

You are done ...!

Comment: Good answer, bear in mind that when you give the executable path of the geckodriver you need to include the entire exe address. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919932/selenium-3-0-2-error-with-firefox-50-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions/41927549#41927549

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this, I deleted the `egg` that was installed and reinstalled selenium, it works perfectly now.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by `egg`, because i am having the same problem.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on MacOS Big Sur and it's a security issue.  To resolve it, go to your system preferences -> Security & Privacy and at the bottom it will complain about geckodriver.  You need to click "Allow Anyway."