# Selenium 3.0.2 error with Firefox 50: executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Selenium 3.0.2 with Firefox 50.0.1 in Windows 7. I've followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312903/running-webdriver-with-firefox-python) post to setup correctly the driver and the paths but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ixps-bgp.he.net.py", line 38, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,capabilities=caps, executable_path='<path to gecko driver>')
  File "C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions.

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x00000000023BA240>> ignored
```

Even when I try to execute the script as administrator I still get the error above. I'm using the latest version of the gecko driver (0.13) and I tried both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions. Is this a known issue with any of the current versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use entire exe address. If you pass just the folder you'll have problems.

```
>>>chromepath = "C:\\Dev\\chromedriver.exe"
>>>driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it and it works both with the Chrome webdriver and the geckodriver for Firefox.