# Webdriver does not access webpage no matter what browser I use

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access a webpage using Selenium's webdriver, but no matter what browser I use (Opera/Firefox/GoogleChrome) I can't access the webpage.

In any of the cases, the browser pops-up and hangs there, does not access any URL.

When I try to run my script, I get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/[opera/chrome]
```

If I use firefox I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/firefox unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

My code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FIREFOX_PATH)

browser.get('www.google.com')
r = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, PARSER)
print(r.text)
```

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 18.04 with python3.6

Comment: You didn't set up path to Geckodriver. Please take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312903/running-webdriver-with-firefox-python

Answer (score 1):

Since you created the webdriver with `executable_path=FIREFOX_PATH`, I think you might have mixed up the keyword arguments for the paths to the Firefox binary and to the geckodriver binary. [`webdriver.Firefox`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html) expects:

> - `firefox_binary` – Instance of FirefoxBinary or full path to the Firefox binary. If undefined, the system default Firefox installation will be used.
> - `executable_path` – Full path to override which geckodriver binary to use for Firefox 47.0.1 and greater, which defaults to picking up the binary from the system path.

So for the Firefox binary `firefox` you need to set keyword argument `firefox_binary`. For geckodriver binary `geckodriver` you need to set keyword argument `executable_path`.

---

Do you even want/need to use other than the default binaries? Can you run

```
firefox --version
```

and

```
geckodriver --version
```

in your terminal without issues? Then you don't need to set `firefox_binary` or `executable_path` at all.