# Trying to use Selenium on a Raspberry Pi2 (Stretch)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, stretch

I have the following configuration:

- `Raspberry Pi2` with Stretch

  - `Python 2.7` with pip installed
  - `Firefox 52.9.0` (from apt-get install firefox-esr)
  - `geckodriver 0.17.0` (from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.17.0/geckodriver-v0.17.0-arm7hf.tar.gz), copied to /usr/local/bin
  - `Selenium 3.4.0`

So according to https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html, this should work.
However, running this simple python script:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
print browser.title
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

returns the error:

> Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11

I tried many things like update Selenium/geckodriver to latest releases, tried some releases in between (Selenium 3.0.2, Geckodriver 0.11.1 as stated in [Selenium Firefox webdriver results in error: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312903/selenium-firefox-webdriver-results-in-error-service-geckodriver-unexpectedly-ex)) but still same error -11 (crash).

Any idea or working configuration?
Thanks,
Jean

Comment: Interesting... Where I try to run geckodriver (./geckodriver) I get segmentation fault or illegal instruction whatever version I'm using. I don't get it, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK this segmentation fault is the root cause, actually my rPI2 is ARM6 and geckodriver is available for ARM7 only:

- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/796
- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/560

So I have to go compile it for ARM6 or use a RPI3.
Unless someone already compiled it for ARM6?

Answer (score 0):

The crash could happen due to geckodriver being compiled for ARMV7, which is not compatible with some armv6 raspberry models. (while amrv7 is compatible with armv6)

Some similar problem, link from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=189633

So, solution would be compiling geckodriver for armv6, luckily somebody already compiled it for ARM6:

https://github.com/d0ku/GeckoDriver_ARMv6