# Python module not importing

Tags: python, module, cmake, package

I am attempting to install a `c++ / python` based library that offers musical onset detection.  Typically, I run `sudo pip install foo` and `cmd+tab` over to PyCharm and type `import ...` and I get auto-completion as I noticed the package resides in `Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.  However, after completing the installation process for this library, no such auto-complete is there.

The complete list of instructions entail using cmake as well as running a setup script for python.  I am unsure about the underlying architectural details (whether its a C++ lib with a python binding, or something..) and whether that plays into my problem.  Here, the installation process is:

[image]

It seems that all the `cmake / c++` building went of with few warnings and no errors, so that is fine..  and so did the python setups..  I do notice a new python package in the 2.7/site-packages dir in the egg format.  Yet import mod.. sees nothing.  Just compilation errors.

Is there anything I could have done wrong in the installation process or in the importing that would solve this problem?  Any help in advance is greatly appreciated.  Let me know if more details are needed to diagnosis the problem.

Comment: "*Just compilation errors.*" What compilation errors?

Comment: "no module named.."

basically, it doesn't see anything to import.  no auto-complete.

Comment: I tried forcing it with the full name but the dir for the package is `modal-1.11-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg` so i dunno what is correct here

Comment: The .egg file is probably either a stub or a zip file.  It sounds to me that it did not install.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg

Comment: To add a directory name to the search path either modify environment variable `PYTHONPATH` or append the name to `sys.path` before the `import`.

Comment: no, the `---.egg` i listed was a directory with all the same files all my other packages in site-packages contain

Comment: I believe, the lib name, the outputs both from CMake build procedure and `setup.py` may really help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Don't have the rep to comment, yet - therefore I had to write an answer.

Just a wild guess, but do you use a virtual environment? If so, did you `pip install` the package globally or into your virtualenv? You might also check if pycharm is using the exact version of python where your package resides.

Comment: this installation process is a bit more tricky than the usual pip install.  its a c++  and python install.  And no, the resulting package dir is in the same site-packages dir that all my other modules/packages are in.